# Return position of an element in Arraylist using Lambda in Java

Tags: java, lambda, collections

I am traversing over my allRecords list that is of type Abc using an iterator. To keep track of the elements
iterated, i keep a position variable.

I use this position variable to further apply some logic in my program.

Code snippet is as follows:

```
Abc abc;
Iterator<Abc> iterator = allRecords.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  abc = iterator.next();
  position++;
  //validate the abc object with some conditions and break the loop if matches
  //I will have that position where the condition matched
}
```

My question is can I use some of Java's latest stream API or lambda expression to fulfill this task.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the point of streams would be avoiding things like indexes, what are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by something like this

```
IntStream.range(0, allRecords.length)
     .filter(i -> allRecords[i].length() <= i)
     .mapToObj(i -> allRecords[i])
```

However Stream API design to make internal iteration possible and you shouldn't concern with index when you use this api.

refer to this post for more info on [External and internal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/224663/1422297) iteration.