# The purpose of the Traversable typeclass

Tags: haskell

Could someone please explain to me, what is the purpose of the typeclass `Traversable`?

The typeclass definition is:

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable (t :: * -> *) where
```

So `Traversable` is a `Functor t` and `Foldable t`.

The `traverse` function is a member of `Traversable` and has the following signature:

```
traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

Why does the result have to be wrapped into an applicative? What is the sense of it?

I have the following example:

```
module ExercisesTraversable where

  import Test.QuickCheck (Arbitrary, arbitrary)
  import Test.QuickCheck.Checkers (quickBatch, eq, (=-=), EqProp)
  import Test.QuickCheck.Classes (traversable)

  type TI = []

  newtype IdentityT a = IdentityT a
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

  instance Functor IdentityT where
    fmap f (IdentityT a) = IdentityT (f a)

  instance Foldable IdentityT where
    foldMap f (IdentityT a) = f a

  instance Traversable IdentityT where
    traverse f (IdentityT a) = IdentityT <$> f a

  instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (IdentityT a) where
    arbitrary = do
      a <- arbitrary
      return (IdentityT a)

  instance Eq a => EqProp (IdentityT a) where (=-=) = eq

  main = do
    let trigger = undefined :: TI (Int, Int, [Int])
    quickBatch (traversable trigger)
```

Let's take a look at the `traverse` implementation:

```
traverse f (IdentityT a) = IdentityT <$> f a
```

The result type of the application `f a` has to be an applicative, why? Would a functor not be enough?

Comment: Functor would be enough for the `Identity` instance, but that is a trivial instance. It isn't enough for pretty much any recursive type - take a look at the `Traversable []` instance.

Comment: The non-applicative version is called `Functor`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Identity` is a bit of a poor example as it always contains exactly one value. You're right – in this case, a `Functor f` constraint would be sufficient. But clearly, most traversables aren't so structurally trivial.

What `traverse` does is: it “visits”, in some well-specified order, all elements in a container, performs some operation on them, and reconstructs the structure as it was. This is more powerful than either

- `Functor t`, which also allows you to visit/modify all elements and reconstructs the structure, but only completely independent of one another (thus allowing to choose an arbitrary order-of-computation, returning a thunk to the structure before any of the elements have been (lazily) mapped at all, etc.).
- `Foldable t`, which brings the elements in a linear order, but does not reconstruct the structure. Basically, `Foldable` is just the class of containers that can be demoted to a simple list, as witnessed by

  ```
  toList :: Foldable t => t a -> [a]
  ```

  ...or to a concatenation of any monoidal type, via

  ```
  foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
  ```

  Here, the results of the operation on each element are *combined* through the monoid operation (or, in case the are no elements, the result is `mempty`).

In case of `traverse`, the `Applicative f` constraint basically lifts this monoid-combining to something in which you can also reconstruct the structure. The correspondence is

```
mempty      ::   m
pure mempty :: f m
```

and

```
(<>)        ::   m ->   m ->   m
liftA2 (<>) :: f m -> f m -> f m
```

...but in addition, because `f` is also a functor, you can wrap the local results in any data constructor and thus build not only a generic list-like thing but an arbitrary container, including one with the original structure.

Comment: Can you please clarify more about ` traverse` and `Applicative f`, I can not follow.

Comment: Yeah... what do you not understand?

Comment: The last section about `traverse` and `Applicative f`.

Comment: If `traverse` do not a part of Applicative, what is going to happen?

Comment: Well, you can do neither `pure mempty` nor `liftA2 (<>)` without `Applicative`, so no way of combining the individual results.

Comment: "and reconstructs the structure as it was". What's the "structure" here? I understand fmap keeps the structure but how does traverse do that?

Comment: @klabe _by definition_ in the same way. I.e., `traverse (pure . f) ≡ pure . fmap f`.

Answer (score 16):

> The result type of the application f a has to be an applicative, why? Would a functor not be enough?

This is a *fantastic* question. The original [McBride & Paterson](http://strictlypositive.org/Idiom.pdf) paper goes in the other direction: it notices that a lot of computation are applicative in nature (can be rewritten with `pure` and `<*>`). *Then* it notices that certain containers, like `[]`, allow for a function of this type:

```
 idist :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
 idist = ...
```

This we now call `sequence` in the `Traversable` class. All well and good, but it helps to probe the *strength* of our assumptions when we write abstractions. What if we tried to build a traversable library without `Applicative`, using only `Functor`? What exactly would go wrong?

### Products!

For this it helps to read through the [Jaskelioff & Rypacek](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.2919.pdf) paper that tries to pin down structures in category theory that correspond to applicative functors and traversable containers. The most interesting property of traversable containers is that they are *closed* under finite *sums* and *products*. This is great for Haskell programming, where a vast number of datatypes can be defined with sums and products:

```
data WeirdSum a = ByList [a] | ByMaybe (Maybe a)

instance Traversable WeirdSum where
  traverse a2fb (ByList as) =
    ByList <$> traverse a2fb as
  traverse a2fb (ByMaybe maybeA) =
    ByMaybe <$> traverse a2fb maybeA
```

Ah, more evidence that we do not need all the power of Applicative! We are only using `fmap` here. Now finite products:

```
data WeirdProduct a = WeirdProduct [a] (Maybe a)

instance Traversable WeirdProduct where
  traverse a2fb (WeirdProduct as aMaybe) =
    WeirdProduct <$> traverse a2fb as <*> traverse a2fb aMaybe
```

Here it is impossible to write a definition with *just* functors: `fmap` is great for sums but gives us no way to "glue" together two different functorial values. It is only with `<*>` that we are able to "close" traversable containers over finite products.

This is all well and good but lacks precision. We are sort of cherry-picking evidence here that `Functor` might be bad, but could we argue from first principles that `Applicative` is exactly what we need, no more and no less?

### Category theory!

This problem is tackled in the second half of the Jaskelioff & Rypacek paper. In category-theoretic terms, a functor `T` is traversable iff it allows for a family of natural transformations

```
{ sequence | sequence : TFX -> FTX, any applicative F }
```

where each natural transformation is "natural in F" and respects the "[monoidal structure of applicative functor composition](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/02/06/applicative-functors/)." It is that last phrase, that last little piece of jargon, where it is important to have `Applicative` rather than `Functor`. With `Applicative f`, we are able to glue together values of type `f a` and `f b`, where we either act on them (a la `foo <$> fa <*> fb` where `foo :: a -> b -> c` and `fa, fb :: f a, f b`) or just shove them into a tuple `f (a, b)`. This gives rise to the aforementioned "monoidal structure"; we need this to then prove that traversable functors are closed over finite products, just like we showed above. Without applicatives we couldn't even begin talking about how functors and products interact! If **Hask** is our category of Haskell types, then an applicative is just a way to name **Hask**-to-**Hask** endofunctors that "behave well" around `(->)` types and product types.

Hopefully this two-pronged answer, one in practical programming and one in categorical foo-foo, gives a little intuition as to why you want applicative functors when talking about traversability. I think often traversables are introduced with an element of magic around them, but they are very much motivated by practical concerns with solid theoretical foundations. Other language ecosystems may have easier-to-use iteration patterns and libraries, but I for one love the simplicity and elegance of `traverse` and `sequence`.

Answer (score 13):

`Traversable` in Haskell unifies the concept of mapping over a container (getting a similary-shaped container in return) with the concept of ["internal iterator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224648/external-iterator-vs-internal-iterator) that performs an effect for each element.

Compared to external iterators, internal iterators are constrained in that we can't use a value obtained for one element to decide what to do with other elements. We can't say "mmmm, if the operation returns 7 for some element, launch the missiles when processing the next one".

This type of "rigid" computations, that can't change course based on values determined mid-way, is represented in Haskell by the `Applicative` typeclass. That's the reason `Traversable` (the containers) and `Applicative` (the effects) go hand-in-hand. `Functor` is not enough because it doesn't provide a method to combine effectful actions.

Allowing any kind of `Applicative` effect is a boon; it means we can traverse a container performing IO, [existing early from failure](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html#t:Either), [collecting log messages](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Strict.html), [collecting error messages from failed iterations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Lift.html#g:2), [iterating concurrently](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.1.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#t:Concurrently)... or [any combination](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) of those effects.

Comment: The "Compared to ..." part can be misunderstood, I think. Surely the IO monad allows to check for 7, save it in some ref, and fire missiles later on when processing the next element.

Comment: @chi But the IO action that will read the reference is "fixed" in a sense. It depends only on the current element. You can't choose *not* to read a reference depending on previous results!

Comment: I completely agree, but it's quite subtle. You don't have _direct_ access to the value the previous IO action returned. You do have access to the same references, in which one might choose to save the previously returned value. A "fixed" IO action could start by (unconditionally!) accessing a reference to a log of what was done before, and then depending on it, choosing whether to access other references.