# What is the relationship between Applicative, Foldable and Traversable?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand what exactly is needed from the `Applicative` interface in order to perform any `traverse`. I'm stuck as they are not used in the default implementation as if the constraint was to strict. Is Haskell's type system too weak to describe the actual requirements?

```
-- | Map each element of a structure to an action, evaluate these actions
-- from left to right, and collect the results. For a version that ignores
-- the results see 'Data.Foldable.traverse_'.
traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
traverse f = sequenceA . fmap f

-- | Evaluate each action in the structure from left to right, and
-- and collect the results. For a version that ignores the results
-- see 'Data.Foldable.sequenceA_'.
sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
sequenceA = traverse id
```

A possibly related side question, why is `sequenceA_` defined in `Foldable`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The purpose of the Traversable typeclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798242/the-purpose-of-the-traversable-typeclass)

Comment: The 2nd question seems completely unrelated to the 1st. But the answer is simple: `Foldable` is strong enough to implement `sequenceA_`.

Answer (score 4):

`traverse` and `sequenceA` both need to deal with what happens when the `Traversable` is empty. Then you won't have any elements in an `Applicative` context that you can use to glom other stuff onto so you'll need `pure`.

The definitions you've presented are a bit misleading since, as you pointed out, they're mutually dependent. When you go to actually implement one of them you'll run into the empty collection problem. And you'll run into the need for `<*>` as `Functor` provides no facility to aggregate different values of `f a` for some functor `f`.

Therefore the `Applicative` constraint is there because for most types, in order to implement either `traverse` or `sequenceA` you'll need the tools that `Applicative` provides.

That being said there are certain types where you don't need `pure` or don't need `<*>`. If your collection can never be empty you don't need `pure`, e.g. `NonEmpty`. If your collection never has more than one element you don't need `<*>`, e.g. `Maybe`. Sometimes you don't need either and you can get away with just `fmap`, e.g. a tuple section such as `(a,)`).

Haskell could have a more fine-grained typeclass hierarchy that breaks `Applicative` down into more fine-grained parts with separate classes for `pure` and `<*>` which would then allow you to make different versions of `Traversable` with weaker constraints.  Edward Kmett's library `semigroupoids` goes in this direction, although it isn't perfect since it can't add actual superclasses to the `base` classes. It has `Apply` which is `Applicative` but without `pure`, and `Traversable1` which is a variant of `Traversable` that uses `Apply` instead of `Applicative` and thus requires that its types can never be empty.

Note that other ecosystems have chosen to have a more fine-grained typeclass hierarchy (see Scala's `cats` or `scalaz` libraries). I personally find such a distinction occasionally useful but not overwhelmingly so.

As for your second question if all you know how to do is tear down something, you can still perform effects  along the way but you can't necessarily recover the original structure. Hence why `sequenceA_` is in `Foldable`. It is strictly less powerful than `sequenceA`.

Comment: "Haskell could have a more fine-grained typeclass hierarchy that breaks `Applicative` down into more fine-grained parts with separate classes for `pure` and `<*>`" -- PureScript has this, defining `Apply` (`<*>`) and `Applicative` (`pure`) as separate type classes.