# Java 8 - Calling a multi argument method from Collection.stream.map()

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I've been using the java 8 Streams for a while. I came across a situation where I need to stream through a List and pass each element to a static method along with another argument. Is it possible in java 8?

```
........
String designation = "Engineer";
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("ABC");
names.add("DEF");
names.add("GHI");
names.stream().map(MyClass::createReport);
..........

class MyClass {
    public static void createReport(String name, String designation) {
       System.out.println(name+"\t"+designation);
    }
}
```

How can I pass the designation String via stream().map()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a lambda expression:

```
names.stream().map(name -> MyClass.createReport(name,designation))...
```

Comment: Note that designation must be final or effectively final in order to use it inside a lambda expression.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a [curried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) version of the method `createReport`.

## Curried `createReport`

We need to swap the order of the arguments because the `designation` for each `name` is the same. Additionly we just need to call the not curried method.

```
Function<String, Consumer<String>> createReportCurry = (designation) -> (name) -> {
    createReport(name, designation);
};
```

## In Action

```
names.stream().forEach(createReportCurry.apply(designation))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following as an alternative:

```
IntStream.range(0, names.size())
         .forEach(i -> MyClass.createReport(names.get(i), names.get(i)));
```

Comment: why the intstream?

Comment: designation was actually set/known from outside, so you may want to keep that and yes... why intstream? Erans answer is probably already simple enough...

Comment: @Felk : How else would I get the index?

Comment: you don't need to... you can just use the stream on the list itself and use its contents (i.e. the `name`)... just check Erans answer...

Comment: Well, its another alternative.

Comment: that's true... but still, you may want to use `designation` as the second parameter, as that's also what the OP has used ;-)

Comment: One of the benefits of using streams or `Collection.forEach()` is that they provide internal iteration through functional APIs. When using an `IntStream` to generate list indexes, you are back to external iteration and thus more or less the same as `for(int i; i < names.size(); i++)`. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/224648/525036) and [this video from Venkat Subramaniam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnL8GB_d4bs)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer are very good but let's try to explain why you couldn't run your code in the first place:

**Your code:**

```
names.stream().map(MyClass::createReport);names.stream().map(MyClass::createReport);
```

**What the JVM undertands**

```
names.stream().map(MyClass::createReport);names.stream().map(name -> MyClass.createReport(name));
```

**Solutions**
use a basic lamba as @Eran or a Function as @Roman suggested.