# Java 8 - Stream - value update while collecting

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In extension the previous question [Java 8 - Calling a multi argument method from Collection.stream.map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541030/java-8-calling-a-multi-argument-method-from-collection-stream-map), how can we update the values while collecting in `collect()` after `stream().map()` process?

```
String designation = "Engineer";
String preFix = "PRE_FIX";
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("ABC");
names.add("DEF");
names.add("GHI");
System.out.println(
    names.stream()
         .map(name -> 
              MyClass.createReport(name, designation))
         .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll));
```

---

```
public static String createReport(String name, String designation) {
   return ("Name:" + name + " - Designation:" + designation);
}
```

Output:

```
[Name:ABC - Designation:Engineer, Name:DEF - Designation:Engineer, 
 Name:GHI - Designation:Engineer]
```

Expected:

```
[PRE_FIX->Name:ABC - Designation:Engineer, PRE_FIX->Name:DEF - 
 Designation:Engineer, PRE_FIX->Name:GHI - Designation:Engineer]
```

Comment: `....map(name -> preFix + "->" + MyClass.createReport(name, designation))..`

Comment: your asking the question in SOF. and u have given the answer... what is this prasad.

Answer (score 4):

Use another `map()`

```
System.out.println(
      names.stream()
           .map(name -> FolderDiffGenerator.createReport(name, 
                        designation))**
           .map(result -> preFix + "->" +result)**
           .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the prefix before the invocation to `createReport`:

```
names.stream()
     .map(name -> preFix + "->" + MyClass.createReport(name, designation))
     .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

On another note, `.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);` can be simplified to `.collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));`:

```
names.stream()
     .map(name -> preFix + "->" + MyClass.createReport(name, designation))
     .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```