# Is there any Relation between Iterator.hasNext and for-each loop

Tags: java, list, foreach, iterator, jprofiler

I was using `JProfiler` for profiling of my application, as it is a huge application so I am very aware of its performance and efficiency.
It was taking too long so I replace all `Iterator.hasNext` with `for-each` but when I am seeing in the JProfilers CPU view it is showing me `Iterator.hasNext` method called where I am using `for-each`.
Why does so? Is there any relation between these two?
Here is the example code :

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> mapList = jdbcTemplate
                        .queryForList(MAP.SELECT_ALL);
                for (Map<String, Object> map : mapList) {
            list.add(fillPreferenceMaster(preferenceMasterMap));
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator they are the same thing when generated to bytecode

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the enhanced `for` statement uses `Iterator` under-the-covers for iterable collections, see [Section 14.14.2 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2):

> If the type of *Expression* is a subtype of `Iterable`, then let *I* be the type of the expression *Expression*`.iterator()`. The enhanced `for` statement is equivalent to a basic `for` statement of the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>         VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier = #i.next();
>    Statement
> }
> ```
>
> Where `#i` is a compiler-generated identifier that is distinct from any other identifiers (compiler-generated or otherwise) that are in scope (§6.3) at the point where the enhanced `for` statement occurs.

Answer (score 2):

The for-each loop in Java uses the underlying iterator mechanism. So to answer your question, the code is identical.

This is most likely not a bottleneck in your code.  You should identify the top 10 method hotspots using JProfiler and find out how to optimize those method calls.

Comment: I am doing that but most of the time is taken by jsp methods and they are visible in very strange manner.

I don't know which tag is taking too much time......

Answer (score 0):

The for-each statement uses the iterator to iterate over your collection. The compiler replaces your for-each with a while loop.