# PHP SPL ArrayIterator v simple foreach

Tags: php, spl

Ok, just as the title says: what are the main benefits of using an ArrayIterator over a simple foreach loop.

I have an object which is being used as a container, its primary responsibility is storing an array of objects.

Someone suggested to me to make my class implement IteratorAggregate and return an ArrayIterator with my array of objects in: like this:

```
  public function getIterator()
  {  
    return new ArrayIterator($this->_objs);  
  }
```

I cant see any benefits to this as opposed to simply returning the array and then using a standard foreach to loop over them.

Please can someone explain why this would be a good idea?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator) will be interesting for you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Returning an array exposes the internal structure of the object. Using an iterator is more abstract.

I don't know what your class does or which is more appropriate in your case. But as a general rule of thumb, if the only realistic use-case is to iterate over the data, then you should return an iterator.

Answer (score 7):

The benefits of implementing `ArrayAccess` is simple: You can access the whole object or just a very specific, even `private` property as array.

In this very simple example, we use `Iterator` and `ArrayAccess` to have access to a specific property named `$array`.

```
class Foo implements \ArrayAccess, \Iterator
{
    public $pointer = 0;

    private $array = [
        'first value',
        'second value',
        'third value',
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pointer = 0;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return $this->array[ $this->pointer ];
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return $this->pointer;
    }

    public function next()
    {
        ++$this->pointer;
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->pointer = 0;
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return isset( $this->array[ $this->position ] );
    }
}
```

We can now loop through it like we would loop through every array:

```
$foo = new Foo();
foreach ( $foo as $key => $value )
{
    print "Index: {$key} - Value: {$value}".PHP_EOL;
}
```

As seen in the previous example, we need to implement all that methods just to loop trough and have access to already present data. And to implement `ArrayAccess`, which allows us to actually **set** values, we'll have to implement another set of methods:

```
ArrayAccess {
    abstract public boolean offsetExists ( mixed $offset )
    abstract public mixed offsetGet ( mixed $offset )
    abstract public void offsetSet ( mixed $offset , mixed $value )
    abstract public void offsetUnset ( mixed $offset )
}
```

Now we can totally leave off writing and repeating that (current/key/next/etc) set of methods, by simply using `IteratorAggregate`. This sums it **into a single, mandatory method**: `getIterator()`.

Now we'd have a **resulting class** like this:

```
class Bar implements \ArrayAccess, \IteratorAggregate
{
    private $array = [];

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return new ArrayIterator( $this->array );
    }
}
```

And we have full array access to the classes `$array` property. We can set and unset values, check if they return `isset`, can loop through them etc. Much more convenient. And it does **exactly the same thing as all those eight methods above**, just by implementing `IteratorAggregate`.

A last note: You'll likely do one more step and implement `Traversable` as well. This interface is very nice, as it allows you to make implementing either `Iterator` or `IteratorAggregate` mandatory without explicitly stating which one the implementing developer needs to use. It just explains that it is mandatory that the object has to be loopable.

```
$foo = new IteratorContainerController();
$foo->addDependency( Traversable $bar );
```

This means that the Dependency for `IteratorContainerController()` will always be either an `Iterator` or an `IteratorAggregate` implemented object. So someone can simply throw an `IteratorAggregate` in or, if s/he needs more fine grained control or does pre-processing of variables before they get set, s/he can simply use `Iterator`.