# Two types of for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

Is there a difference in terms of efficiency between

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
for (int item : numbers) {
   System.out.println("Count is: " + item);
}
```

and

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   System.out.println("Count is: " + numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: @John check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the same for arrays. If you have an orders list of numbers you should use

```
for(int i = min; i <= max; max += stride)
```

or

```
for(int i = min; i < max+stride; max += stride)
```

e.g.

```
for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
```

or

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
```

or if incrementing by 10

```
for(int j = 0; j <= 100; j += 10)
```

if you a predefined list of values to use, you can use an array.

I often write them like this

```
for (int item : new int[] {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100}) 
   System.out.println("Count is: " + item);
```

Comment: -1.  Sorry, IMO, his style should only be used if the values are not in order.  For i=1..10 style loops have been a standard and successful language idiom for longer than many of us have been alive.  In your style, a support programmer has to read all 10 ints to check if these are in order.

Comment: @user949300 Good point, using an array is not a good idea if you have a sequence.

Comment: I like your new example where the array is not a sequence but a "vaguely logarithmic" series of numbers.  So I'll undo the -1.

Comment: @user949300 I use "vaguely logarithmic" searches for parameter optimisation quite a bit these days.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the bytecode generated for both of your code snippets will be almost exactly the same. You can check this with tools like javap, or even view it in Eclipse's decompiled class viewer.

Comment: Only for arrays. For `Collection`s they are completely different.

Comment: @SteveKuo There are two pieces of code in OP's question. The generated bytecode will be almost exactly the same. Your comment makes little sense.

Comment: Let me be more clear. For a `Collection`, indexing vs iterator can be vastly different, depending on the collection implementation (such as `LinkedList`).

Comment: I think SteveKuo is trying to say that although the generated code in this particular example would be very similar, if instead of being an array the structure being traversed was, say, a LinkedList, then the two would be different. He's not saying that your answer is wrong, just adding a point of potential interest.

Comment: @SteveKuo That is true, but I still don't see the point of bringing it up for this particular question. Iterating over a `List` by indexing is bad practice, anyway, so I don't assume OP or anyone else would write it like that.

Answer (score 3):

For `Array []`, its similar but for `Collections` such as `ArrayList`, it will be different.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are doing something extremely strange inside the loop, the difference in performance will be undetectable.  Whatever the answer to the question, this is a "penny wise, pound foolish" optimization.  The decision should be made on what capabilities you need and which code is clearer.  (IMO, Option 1 is simpler and clearer, though sometimes you need Option 2)

You have probably spent more time typing the question and reading answers than the added time spent in the loop for the life of your program.  :-)

Not sure where to ask this, but I think there should be some "premature optimization" tag we can add to questions like this one.

Answer (score 0):

It will be very similar in performance so is up to you choose your favorite. For me a for-each is always more elegant but each programmer is different ^^