# Getting all names in an enum as a String[]

Tags: java, arrays, enums

What's the easiest and/or shortest way possible to get the names of enum elements as an array of `String`s?

What I mean by this is that if, for example, I had the following enum:

```
public enum State {
    NEW,
    RUNNABLE,
    BLOCKED,
    WAITING,
    TIMED_WAITING,
    TERMINATED;

    public static String[] names() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

the `names()` method would return the array `{ "NEW", "RUNNABLE", "BLOCKED", "WAITING", "TIMED_WAITING", "TERMINATED" }`.

Comment: Why there is not a native Enum method that does exactly that it's beyond me... and also a get(index) to simplify the get of value()

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Here's one-liner for any `enum` class:

```
public static String[] getNames(Class<? extends Enum<?>> e) {
    return Arrays.stream(e.getEnumConstants()).map(Enum::name).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Pre Java 8 is still a one-liner, albeit less elegant:

```
public static String[] getNames(Class<? extends Enum<?>> e) {
    return Arrays.toString(e.getEnumConstants()).replaceAll("^.|.$", "").split(", ");
}
```

That you would call like this:

```
String[] names = getNames(State.class); // any other enum class will work
```

If you just want something simple for a hard-coded enum class:

```
public static String[] names() {
    return Arrays.toString(State.values()).replaceAll("^.|.$", "").split(", ");
}
```

Comment: Not the fastest ways to do the job, but nice regex.

Comment: In Java 8 solution, outside a method scope, instead of `e.getEnumConstants()` you may use `YourEnumName.values()`

Comment: @Eido95 using `YourEnumName.values()` is calling a static method on the class, which cannot be reused for *any* enum. Using `getEnumConstants()` works for *any* enum class. The idea with this method is to recreate a utility method that you can call like the last line of the answer.

Comment: if you want a custom label for your enum, override toString() in your enum class.

Comment: Can you please explaing `Class<? extends Enum<?>> e`?

Comment: @Carmageddon `Class<? extends Enum<?>> e` basically means "any `enum` class", and in more detail means `e` is a `Class` whose type is (or is a subtype of) `Enum<?>`. All `enum` classes implicitly extend the `Enum` class, whose type is a self-referencing type, ie `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`

Comment: No need to use Streams. A simple `for` loop and a temporary array would do the trick.

Comment: @BoškoBezik there’s no need to ever use streams for anything, but they make the code neater and hopefully easier to read, which is code’s purpose.

Answer (score 66):

Create a `String[]` array for the names and call the static `values()` method which returns all the enum values, then iterate over the values and populate the names array.

```
public static String[] names() {
    State[] states = values();
    String[] names = new String[states.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        names[i] = states[i].name();
    }

    return names;
}
```

Comment: Why call `values()` 13 times, generating a new array each time, instead of caching the array in a local variable? Why use toString(), which is overridable, instead of `name()`?

Comment: @JBNizet heheh, i actually tried this in my IDE and way to lazy to create an State array i guess, hehe, anyways iedited it now :)

Comment: You're still not returning the names, but the toString() values.

Comment: @JBNizet hmm, tbh, i dint really know there was a `name()` method untill now. how stupid of me :P thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: I accepted this answer, but I submitted an edit that improves the code so it's easier to read.

Comment: Any reason not to use ordinal() for the index and a for each loop, like:

    for (State state: State.values() {
        names[state.ordinal()] = state.toString();
    }

Comment: Shouldn't it be 
`State[] states = State.values();`

Comment: @PermGenError, I would like to know how to return the values (English, L1) , L1 being the value; after comparing the arrays of string with the Enums arrays.  For example, the String Arrays contains English, etc etc, but I want to return a list of L1, L2 etc if it matches the ones in the Enums.

Answer (score 27):

If you can use Java 8, this works nicely (alternative to Yura's suggestion, more efficient):

```
public static String[] names() {
    return Stream.of(State.values()).map(State::name).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Here`s an elegant solution using [*Apache Commons Lang 3*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/):

```
EnumUtils.getEnumList(State.class)
```

Although it returns a List, you can convert the list easily with `list.toArray()`

Comment: `EnumUtils.getEnumList(enumClass)` returns the enum values, not the Strings. You could use `EnumUtils.getEnumMap(enumClass).keySet()`, but the order might be different.

Answer (score 13):

With java 8:

```
Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values()).map(Enum::name)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray();
```

Comment: While it probably works, this implementation is quite inefficient, first creating an ArrayList, adding all elements, then creating an array and copying everything again.

Comment: Any time soon "everyone" will be using streams to accomplish the most basic operations... and that is not a very good idea.

Comment: considering the fact that the number of elements in enums is usually rather small, I think that Yura's solution will be fine for many use cases. Naturally, it will depend on the specific situation...

Answer (score 6):

I would write it like this

```
public static String[] names() {

    java.util.LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (State s : State.values()) {
        list.add(s.name());
    }

    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another ways :

First one

```
Arrays.asList(FieldType.values())
            .stream()
            .map(f -> f.toString())
            .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Other way

```
Stream.of(FieldType.values()).map(f -> f.toString()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: In *this* case `toString()` works, but in the general case it does not, because `toString()` can be be overridden. Use `.name()` to reliably get the instance *name* as a String.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would do:

```
public static String[] names() {
  String[] names = new String[values().length];
  int index = 0;

  for (State state : values()) {
    names[index++] = state.name();
  }

  return names;
}
```

[The documentation recommends using `toString()` instead of `name()` in most cases](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29), but you have explicitly asked for the name here.

Comment: Although it doesn't particularly matter, a regular for loop offers better performance than a foreach loop in this situation. Plus, `values()` is called twice when it need only be called once.

Comment: @Vulcan I think performance would only be an issue with this if it were run hundreds of thousands of times. Besides, `values()` is a method generated by the compiler, so I'm guessing it's pretty optimized. Finally, I remember reading somewhere that for-each loops are more efficient than standard, incremental for loops, but then again — [it just doesn't matter](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/micro-optimization-and-meatballs.html).

Comment: @Konstantin considering that the foreach loop in java is implemented with a standard for loop, where ever you read that foreach loops are ever more efficient is incorrect.

Comment: @sage88 I was referring to for loops in which you retrieve elements using a numeric index, which you increment in each cycle. For example:
`for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) /* do stuff */;`
In this case, for-each loops _are_, in fact, more efficient.

A quick SO search on the matter gives us this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator

Comment: @Konstantin Any time you have a data structure that allows random access, as is the case with enum values, which returns an array, a C-style for loop is faster than using a for each loop. The for each loop has to generate an iterator, which makes it slower. The link you posted gives an example of using a standard for loop on a linked list using get(i), which is of course worse. When using a non-random access data structure the for each loop is faster, but on arrays it has a greater overhead. Also, since it's a primitive array, not an ArrayList, there's no performance hit from .size().

Comment: Though I should say that I was wrong above, for each does't use a standard for loop, it uses an iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Got the simple solution

```
Arrays.stream(State.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 2):

i'd do it this way (but i'd probably make names an unmodifiable set instead of an array):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
enum State {
    NEW,RUNNABLE,BLOCKED,WAITING,TIMED_WAITING,TERMINATED;
    public static final String[] names=new String[values().length];
    static {
        State[] values=values();
        for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++)
            names[i]=values[i].name();
    }
}
public class So13783295 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(State.names));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd do something like this as well if I needed to repeatedly get the enum names, but since the `names()` method is only called sparingly, I think generating an array on the spot is fine.

Answer (score 2):

My solution, with manipulation of strings (not the fastest, but is compact):

```
public enum State {
    NEW,
    RUNNABLE,
    BLOCKED,
    WAITING,
    TIMED_WAITING,
    TERMINATED;

    public static String[] names() {
        String valuesStr = Arrays.toString(State.values());
        return valuesStr.substring(1, valuesStr.length()-1).replace(" ", "").split(",");
    }
}
```

Comment: and java7 compliant!

Answer (score 2):

the ordinary way (pun intended):

```
String[] myStringArray=new String[EMyEnum.values().length];
for(EMyEnum e:EMyEnum.values())myStringArray[e.ordinal()]=e.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need and use a generic method (inside an ArrayUtils class):

```
public static <T> String[] toStringArray(T[] array) {
    String[] result=new String[array.length];
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        result[i]=array[i].toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

And just define a STATIC inside the enum...

```
public static final String[] NAMES = ArrayUtils.toStringArray(values());
```

Java enums really miss a names() and get(index) methods, they are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

org.apache.commons.lang3.EnumUtils.getEnumMap(State.class).keySet()

Comment: What is `EnumUtils`?

Comment: @Stephan https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html

Comment: @wutzebaer downvoting because this soultion isn't complete - it doesn't return array

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit test on @Bohemian's solution. The performance is better when using naive loop instead.

```
public static <T extends Enum<?>> String[] getEnumNames(Class<T> inEnumClass){
    T [] values = inEnumClass.getEnumConstants();
    int len = values.length;
    String[] names = new String[len];
    for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
        names[i] = values[i].name();
    }
    return names;
}

//Bohemian's solution
public static String[] getNames(Class<? extends Enum<?>> e) {
    return Arrays.stream(e.getEnumConstants()).map(Enum::name).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Comment: You should give the statistics about performance, then people can judge for themselves if the performance loss is significant or not. I suppose that most people will not have 100+ or 1000+ values for an Enum.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to the accepted answer, but since I learnt about EnumSet, I can't help but use it everywhere. So for a tiny bit more succinct (Java8) answer:

```
public static String[] getNames(Class<? extends Enum<?>> e) {
  return EnumSet.allOf(e).stream().map(Enum::name).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get Enum String value by "Enum::name"

```
public static String[] names() {
    return Arrays.stream(State.values()).map(Enum::name).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

This implementation does not require additional "function" and "field". Just add this function to get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Basing off from Bohemian's answer for Kotlin:

Use `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()`.

```
Arrays.toString(MyEnum.values()).replace(Regex("^.|.$"), "").split(", ").toTypedArray()
```

Side note: Convert to `.toTypedArray()` for use in `AlertDialog`'s `setSingleChoiceItems`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the shortest you can try

```
public static String[] names() {
    String test = Arrays.toString(values());
    return text.substring(1, text.length()-1).split(", ");
}
```

Comment: Not the shortest :) See my answer for a one-liner (that still only invokes `vales()` once)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: maybe you don't need to create a method to return the values of the enum as an array of strings.

Why do you need the array of strings? Maybe you only need to convert the values when you use them, if you ever need to do that.

Examples:

```
for (State value:values()) {
    System.out.println(value); // Just print it.
}
```

---

```
for (State value:values()) {
    String x = value.toString(); // Just iterate and do something with x.
}
```

---

```
// If you just need to print the values:
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(State.values()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static String[] vratAtributy() {
    String[] atributy = new String[values().length];
    for(int index = 0; index < atributy.length; index++) {
        atributy[index] = values()[index].toString();
    }
    return atributy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it in Java 7 or earlier would be to use Guava:

```
public static String[] names() {
    return FluentIterable.from(values()).transform(Enum::name).toArray(String.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put enum values to list of strings and convert to array:

```
    List<String> stateList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (State state: State.values()) {
                stateList.add(state.toString());
            }

    String[] stateArray = new String[stateList.size()];
    stateArray = stateList.toArray(stateArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
Category[] category = Category.values();
for (int i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(i  + " - " + category[i]);
}
```

Where Category is `Enum` name

Answer (score 0):

```
enum CardType {
    CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE;

}

public class Control {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] cardsArray = new String[CardType.values().length];
        int i = 0;

        for (CardType cardType : CardType.values()){
            cardsArray[i] = cardType.name();
            i++;
        }
        //to output the array
        for (int j = 0; j < CardType.values().length; j++){
            System.out.println(cardsArray[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a new String array. You can then populate it with values() from your enum by using the enhanced for-loop to loop through the enum.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the *Streams API* or the *Apache Commons* library. Here is arguably the simplest and the fastest way to do this:

```
public static String[] names() {
    String[] names = new String[State.values().length];
    State[] values = State.values();
    for (int i = 0, valuesLength = values.length; i < valuesLength; i++) {
        names[i] = values[i].toString();
    }
    return names;
}
```