# Custom validator message: Throwing exception in implementation of ConstraintValidator cause UnexpectedException

Tags: java, spring, validation

So I have custom validator and when I set `return` value to `false` then it works  -

```
import com.vhealth.api.service.UserService;
import com.vhealth.api.utils.exceptions.InvalidPayloadException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;


public class UserNameUniqueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UserNameUnique, String> {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UserNameUnique constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String userName, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (userService.findByUserName(userName) != null) {
            throw new InvalidPayloadException("Creating user requires unique userName new");
            //return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

But when I try throw exception in that section I get error that problem is caused by my custom exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unexpected exception during isValid call
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:932)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:134)
    at com.vhealth.api.controller.ApiUserControllerTest.shouldReturnErrorMessageToAdminWhenCreatingUserWithUsedUserName(ApiUserControllerTest.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unexpected exception during isValid call
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.validator.metadata.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:139)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:772)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.validate(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: com.vhealth.api.utils.exceptions.InvalidPayloadException: Creating user requires unique userName new
    at com.vhealth.api.utils.validators.UserNameUniqueValidator.isValid(UserNameUniqueValidator.java:22)
    at com.vhealth.api.utils.validators.UserNameUniqueValidator.isValid(UserNameUniqueValidator.java:11)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:278)
    ... 90 more
```

Exception is placed in `@Controller ExceptionResolover`

```
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidPayloadException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleEmptyFieldException(InvalidPayloadException ex) {
    return new ResponseEntity(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Edit: Throwing `InvalidPayloadException` exception in `UserNameUniqueValidator` returns custom message so I avoid to use `BindingResult` in main controller for extraction default message from `validaor`

Comment: hibernate is wrapping the exception, you can see the one you're throwing at the bottom of the stack.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you want to display custom message try this piece of code.

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(String userName, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (userService.findByUserName(userName) != null) {
        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        context
            .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("User " + userName + "already exists!")
            .addConstraintViolation();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That worked instantly - I'm still curious about that problem with throwing custom exception from validator however after applying your solution I don't see the point in using exception here :)

Comment: The "context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();" should be at the first line of the method, because if we assume that you have more conditions/validations you will have to repeat it too often

Comment: @mchrobok Similar problem. In my case, I want to throw a custom exception with response HttpStatus wrapped in it from `isValid` method and then return a `ResponseEntity` with that HttpStatus. Any idea how could I achieve this?
`
public boolean isValid() {
    throw new CustomException( HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
}

@ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
public final ResponseEntity<IROResponse> handleException(CustomException ex) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(body, ex.getStatus());
}
`
My call not landing in this exception handler and ValidationException is thrown

Comment: @mantri did you get solution to the issue you faced. I need the same solution

Answer (score 2):

You can add not null check! You can still follow [mchrobok] answer
I think better will be:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(String userName, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (userService !=null && userService.findByUserName(userName) != null) {
        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        context
            .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("User " + userName + "already exists!")
            .addConstraintViolation();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (need to get just exception to handle it in exceptionMapper).
so, You can extend your custom exception from 'ConstraintDeclarationException':

```
public class BusinessValidationException extends ConstraintDeclarationException {

    private ValidationErrorDto validationErrorDto;

    public BusinessValidationException(ValidationErrorDto validationErrorDto) {
        super();
        this.validationErrorDto = validationErrorDto;
    }

    public BusinessValidationException(ValidationErrorDto validationErrorDto, String message, Object... args) {
        super(String.format(message, args));
        this.validationErrorDto = validationErrorDto;
    }
...
}
```

below, you can see how to use it:

```
@Override
    public boolean isValid(RequestDto dto, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        ...

        if (some condition) {
            ...

            throw new BusinessValidationException(validationErrorDto, "Duplicate transaction T[%s]", dto.getTrace());
        }

        return true;
    }
```

and, how to catch it in exceptionMapper:

```
@ExceptionHandler(BusinessValidationException.class)
    public ResponseDto handleBusinessValidationExceptions(BusinessValidationException ex) {
        logger.info(ex.getMessage());

        return new ...;
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is you can't accumulate all the violations. It is good if you wanna throw the exception if you encounter ANY violation and not ALL violations.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any compiler error.
Please check the error thrown is

```
Caused by: com.vhealth.api.utils.exceptions.InvalidPayloadException: Creating user requires unique userName new
    at com.vhealth.api.utils.validators.UserNameUniqueValidator.isValid(UserNameUniqueValidator.java:22)
    at com.vhealth.api.utils.validators.UserNameUniqueValidator.isValid(UserNameUniqueValidator.java:11)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:278)
... 90 more
```

I think it only means that exception you have thrown is a Nested exception

Also check the stacktrace
     at com.vhealth.api.controller.ApiUserControllerTest.shouldReturnErrorMessageToAdminWhenCreatingUserWithUsedUserName(ApiUserControllerTest.java:53)

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unexpected exception during isValid call
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:932)
```