# Catching ValidationException instead of a custom Exception in ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, hibernate-validator, controller-advice

I'm trying to throw an exception inside a custom validator which I built using annotation like that:

**ValidExtractionDate** annotation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = ExtractionDateValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidExtractionDate {
    String message() default "Invalid value for extractionDate";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**ExtractionDateValidator:**

```
public class ExtractionDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidExtractionDate, LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidExtractionDate constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(LocalDate localDate, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (localDate.isAfter(LocalDate.now())) {
            throw new InvalidExtractionDateException("date is set in the future");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

as you see above, an exception of type InvalidExtractionDateException is thrown when localDate is invalid:

**InvalidExtractionDateException:**

```
public class InvalidExtractionDateException extends ValidationException {
    public InvalidExtractionDateException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Inside my ControllerAdvice I have this:

```
/**
 * @param ex a Exception
 * @return a responseEntity with a descriptive message and some other information
 */
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorMessage globalExceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
    LOG.error(ex.getClass().getName());
    ex.printStackTrace();
    LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
    return getErrorMessage();
}

/**
 * @param ex an InvalidExtractionDateException exception
 * @return a responseEntity with a descriptive message and some other information
 */
@ExceptionHandler(InvalidExtractionDateException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorMessage invalidExtractionDateException(InvalidExtractionDateException ex) {
    LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
    return getErrorMessage(ex, ErrorCode.INVALID_INPUT_ERROR);
}
```

Unfortunately after throwing the exception, the **AdviceController** is calling for *globalExceptionHandler()* method instead of *invalidExtractionDateException()* method.

This is what I get on the console:

```
INFO |2021-11-17T15:59:25,890|3E05E9E2F27F439EB625395C6E2A35FD| [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.obs.dqsc.api.controller.validators.ExtractionDateValidator - Entered in ExtractionDateValidator.initialize(@com.obs.dqsc.api.controller.validators.annotation.ValidExtractionDate(message="Invalid value for extractionDate", payload={}, groups={}))
INFO |2021-11-17T15:59:25,895|3E05E9E2F27F439EB625395C6E2A35FD| [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.obs.dqsc.api.controller.validators.ExtractionDateValidator - Exit from ExtractionDateValidator.initialize(..); Execution time: 2 ms;
INFO |2021-11-17T15:59:25,896|3E05E9E2F27F439EB625395C6E2A35FD| [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.obs.dqsc.api.controller.validators.ExtractionDateValidator - Entered in ExtractionDateValidator.isValid(2021-11-29, org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorContextImpl@221131fa)
ERROR|2021-11-17T15:59:25,901|3E05E9E2F27F439EB625395C6E2A35FD| [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.obs.dqsc.api.GlobalExceptionHandler - javax.validation.ValidationException
ERROR|2021-11-17T15:59:25,903|3E05E9E2F27F439EB625395C6E2A35FD| [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.obs.dqsc.api.GlobalExceptionHandler - HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:537)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersForSingleGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:991)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersForGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:932)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:863)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:235)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
    at com.obs.dqsc.api.aspect.LoggingAspect.logMethod(LoggingAspect.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.obs.dqsc.api.controller.CustomerController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$65295c12.test(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.obs.dqsc.api.controller.filter.Slf4jMDCFilter.doFilterInternal(Slf4jMDCFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: com.obs.dqsc.api.exception.functional.InvalidExtractionDateException: date is set in the future
    at com.obs.dqsc.api.controller.validators.ExtractionDateValidator.isValid(ExtractionDateValidator.java:20)
    at com.obs.dqsc.api.controller.validators.ExtractionDateValidator.isValid(ExtractionDateValidator.java:10)
    at com.obs.dqsc.api.controller.validators.ExtractionDateValidator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$73cf36d8.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
    at com.obs.dqsc.api.aspect.LoggingAspect.logMethod(LoggingAspect.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.obs.dqsc.api.controller.validators.ExtractionDateValidator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$db5fdff4.isValid(<generated>)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:180)
    ... 84 more
DEBUG|2021-11-17T15:59:25,964|3E05E9E2F27F439EB625395C6E2A35FD| [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

Comment: As you might guess from the exception message, `isValid` should not throw exceptions but instead just return `false`…

Comment: but I want to throw an exception to handle it after, and return a custom message to the client, I've seen a lot of example where they do the same thing, but it is not working in my case

Comment: when you are throwing this exception from the isValid, the custom exception is getting wrapped, so you are not getting the actual exception while handling it globally. So return false and then raise custom exception or follow this link   

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825563/custom-validator-message-throwing-exception-in-implementation-of-constraintvali