# Get enum values as List of String in Java 8

Tags: java, enums, java-8

Is there any Java 8 method or easy way, which returns Enum values as a List of String, like:

```
List<String> sEnum = getEnumValuesAsString();
```

Comment: What would it mean to get an enum value as a string? Do you want a list of the names of the enum constants?

Comment: @user2357112, values as `list of String`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Enum values are not strings.

Comment: Could you show how you might do this without Java 8?

Comment: @ user2357112 I do agree, enum values are not string, it is it own type but I need the conversion

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You can do (pre-Java 8):

```
List<Enum> enumValues = Arrays.asList(Enum.values());
```

or

```
List<Enum> enumValues = new ArrayList<Enum>(EnumSet.allOf(Enum.class));
```

Using Java 8 features, you can map each constant to its name:

```
List<String> enumNames = Stream.of(Enum.values())
                               .map(Enum::name)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Great answer. Is there any downside of using stream over array to list considering runtime?

Comment: No. Using Streams can actually improve performance, as it can be processed in parallel.

Comment: You can also shorten `asList(...).stream()` slightly by using `Stream.of` or `Arrays.stream`.

Comment: @kocko: That's an oversimplification.  For small amounts of data, streams will usually have a small overhead over arrays, and use of `parallel` can significantly _hurt_ performance; parallelization has a cost that's not always outweighed by the wins.

Comment: First and second solution don't really solve the problem, since OP is asking for array of strings as result. So streams are the only viable solution?

Comment: To join the names into one string so you can log them, replace the collector with `.collect(Collectors.joining(", "))`.

Comment: @kikovi yes it probably is only solution to fit OP answer, but your comment about Streams not capable of hurting performance is not true

Comment: How would you be able to get the names of the Enums into a list? Like `AnimalA("Cow"), AnimalB("Dog")` etc? I want the name, not the name of the Enum itself.

Answer (score 13):

You could also do something as follow

```
public enum DAY {MON, TUES, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN};
EnumSet.allOf(DAY.class).stream().map(e -> e.name()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

or

```
EnumSet.allOf(DAY.class).stream().map(DAY::name).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

The main reason why I stumbled across this question is that I wanted to write a generic validator that validates whether a given string enum name is valid for a given enum type (Sharing in case anyone finds useful).

For the validation, I had to use `Apache's EnumUtils` library since the type of enum is not known at compile time.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public static void isValidEnumsValid(Class clazz, Set<String> enumNames) {
    Set<String> notAllowedNames = enumNames.stream()
            .filter(enumName -> !EnumUtils.isValidEnum(clazz, enumName))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    if (notAllowedNames.size() > 0) {
        String validEnumNames = (String) EnumUtils.getEnumMap(clazz).keySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The requested values '" + notAllowedNames.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + "' are not valid. Please select one more (case-sensitive) "
                + "of the following : " + validEnumNames);
    }
}
```

I was too lazy to write an enum annotation validator as shown in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51109419/1225551

Answer (score 0):

If you need to go to an array, you can do this:

```java
public enum DAY {MON, TUES, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN};

String[] days = Stream.of(DAY.values()).map(Enum::name).toArray(String[]::new);
```