# How do I fill a priority queue with all enum values quickly?

Tags: java, enums, priority-queue

I have an enum and I want to pull all of the enum's options in a priority queue in their natural order priority. Is there a way to do this without adding them one by one. There has to be a one liner I'm missing... Thanks!

Comment: For a `List`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465943/get-enum-values-as-list-of-string-in-java-8/29465971

Comment: That'll do it. Not sure how I missed that...

Comment: @Hackerman I deleted my answer because you and PM77-1 were spot on. Haven't had my coffee today :)