# How to return a proper validation error for enum types in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, enums

I have created a demo spring boot application. The request takes in a car object and returns the same. I am trying to figure out a way to send a proper message to the user if the carType is not a valid enum.

Request

```
{
    "carType": "l"
}
```

Response

```
{
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.example.demo.Car$CarType` from String \"l\": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [Racing, Sedan]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.example.demo.Car$CarType` from String \"l\": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [Racing, Sedan]\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 13] (through reference chain: com.example.demo.Car[\"carType\"])",
    "statusCode": "BAD_REQUEST"
}
```

How can I send a proper message to the user without displaying the class names and the stack trace? I want the user to know what are the valid types of enum but do not want the message to have java error trace. Is there a way to extract proper message having just the field that is erroneous. What is the standard way of validating enums?

**Car.java**

```
import lombok.*;

@Getter
@Setter
public class Car {
     enum CarType {
        Sedan,
        Racing
    }

    CarType carType;
}
```

**DemoControllerAdvice.java**

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class DemoControllerAdvice {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    public ErrorObject handleJsonErrors(HttpMessageNotReadableException exception){

        return new ErrorObject(exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

**DemoController.java**

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @PostMapping("/car")
    public Car postMyCar(@RequestBody Car car){
        return car;
    }
    
}
```

Is there any neat way to achieve using Hibernate Validator but without using a custom hibernate Validator like in the answer below?
[How to use Hibernate validation annotations with enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205787/how-to-use-hibernate-validation-annotations-with-enums)

Comment: A validator won't help as it fails even before that. Jackson cannot convert the string to an enum because the value is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The de-serialisation happens before the validation.

If you want Hibernate to do it, then [you already linked to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205787). Otherwise you'll have to handle the exception yourself.

```java
private static final Pattern ENUM_MSG = Pattern.compile("values accepted for Enum class: \\[([^\\]])\\]");

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public ErrorObject handleJsonErrors(HttpMessageNotReadableException exception) {
    if (exception.getCause() instanceof InvalidFormatException) {
        Matcher match = ENUM_MSG.matcher(exception.getCause().getMessage());
        if (match.test()) {
            return new ErrorObject("value should be: " + match.group(1),  HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    return new ErrorObject(exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```