# Custom Error Handler a spring boot @RequestBody DTO class with ENUM type (updated with validator approach 1 and Updated with validator approach 2)

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, enums

I am trying to figure out how to handle errors using Enum classes as input parameters. What I would like to achieve is some kind of validation where it returns an error message highlighting all the allowed categories.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class UserDTO {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private GenderTypeEnum gender;
    private List<HobbyEnum> hobby;

}
```

and

```
public enum GenderTypeEnum {

    MALE("male"),
    FEMALE("female");


    private final String value;


    private GenderTypeEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getGender(){
        return this.value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static GenderTypeEnum fromValues(String value) {
        for (GenderTypeEnum category : GenderTypeEnum.values()) {
            if (category.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return category;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Unknown enum type " + value + ", Allowed values are " + Arrays.toString(values()));
    }
}
```

and

```
public enum HobbyEnum {

    BIKE("bike"),
    CLIMB("climb"),
    TENNIS("tennis");

    private final String value;


    private HobbyEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getGender(){
        return this.value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static HobbyEnum fromValues(String value) {
        for (HobbyEnum category : HobbyEnum.values()) {
            if (category.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return category;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Unknown enum type " + value + ", Allowed values are " + Arrays.toString(values()));
    }

}
```

and

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
public class UserController {


    @GetMapping(path = "/user")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(

            @RequestBody
            UserDTO user

    ){
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .body(user);

    }
}
```

It currently returns an error message of the following type (e.g., misplacing `male` with `malex`)

[image]

On the Spring Boot console I get this message instead:

```
2023-06-08T18:26:34.233+02:00  WARN 28248 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.enumhandler.enumerator.GenderTypeEnum`, problem: Unknown enum type malex, Allowed values are [MALE, FEMALE]]
```

I implemented a validator in the following way but failed to get the hoped-for message (https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validations-enums)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = GenderTypeEnumSubSetValidator.class)
public @interface GenderTypeEnumSubset {
    GenderTypeEnum[] anyOf();
    String message() default "must be any of {anyOf}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and

```
package com.example.enumhandler.validator;

import com.example.enumhandler.enumerator.GenderTypeEnum;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GenderTypeEnumSubSetValidator
        implements ConstraintValidator<GenderTypeEnumSubset, GenderTypeEnum> {

    private GenderTypeEnum[] subset;

    @Override
    public void initialize(GenderTypeEnumSubset constraint) {
        this.subset = constraint.anyOf();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(GenderTypeEnum value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value == null || Arrays.asList(subset).contains(value);
    }

}
```

and updated class UserDTO

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class UserDTO {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    @GenderTypeEnumSubset(anyOf = {GenderTypeEnum.MALE, GenderTypeEnum.FEMALE})
    private GenderTypeEnum gender;
    private List<HobbyEnum> hobby;

}
```

But in the end I get the same error message as before without improvement:

[image]

I also found this solution [https://medium.com/@vandernobrel/creating-custom-bean-validation-annotations-2c21f5e24b06][4] and I tried to implement:

```
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = GenderTypeEnumSubSetValidator.class)
public @interface GenderTypeEnumSubset {
    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass();
    String message() default "must be any of {anyOf}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and

```
import com.example.enumhandler.enumerator.GenderTypeEnum;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

    public class GenderTypeEnumSubSetValidator
            implements ConstraintValidator<GenderTypeEnumSubset, GenderTypeEnum> {
    
        private List<String> acceptedValues;
    
        @Override
        public void initialize(GenderTypeEnumSubset constraint) {
            acceptedValues = Stream.of(constraint.enumClass().getEnumConstants())
                    .map(Enum::name)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isValid(GenderTypeEnum value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    Arrays.asList(subset).contains(value);
            if(value == null){
                return true;
            }
            return acceptedValues.contains(value.toString());
    
        }
    
    }
```

Updated UserDTO

```
   @AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class UserDTO {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    //@GenderTypeEnumSubset(anyOf = {GenderTypeEnum.MALE, GenderTypeEnum.FEMALE})
    //private GenderTypeEnum gender;
    @GenderTypeEnumSubset(enumClass = GenderTypeEnum.class)
    private String gender;
    private List<HobbyEnum> hobby;

}
```

But again:

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

---

**This is the solution suggested by @Jay Yadav (thanks but again not work):**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>
           spring-boot-starter-validation
        </artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
package com.example.enumhandler.dto;

import com.example.enumhandler.enumerator.GenderTypeEnum;
import com.example.enumhandler.enumerator.HobbyEnum;
import com.example.enumhandler.validator.GenderTypeEnumSubset;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.List;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class UserDTO {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    @GenderTypeEnumSubset(anyOf = {GenderTypeEnum.MALE, GenderTypeEnum.MALE})
    private GenderTypeEnum gender;
    private List<HobbyEnum> hobby;

}
```

and

```
package com.example.enumhandler.enumerator;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

import java.util.Arrays;

public enum GenderTypeEnum {

    MALE("male"),
    FEMALE("female");


    private final String value;


    private GenderTypeEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getGender(){
        return this.value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static GenderTypeEnum fromValues(String value) {
        for (GenderTypeEnum category : GenderTypeEnum.values()) {
            if (category.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return category;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Unknown enum type " + value + ", Allowed values are " + Arrays.toString(values()));
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.example.enumhandler.enumerator;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

import java.util.Arrays;

public enum HobbyEnum {

    BIKE("bike"),
    CLIMB("climb"),
    TENNIS("tennis");

    private final String value;


    private HobbyEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getGender(){
        return this.value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static HobbyEnum fromValues(String value) {
        for (HobbyEnum category : HobbyEnum.values()) {
            if (category.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return category;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Unknown enum type " + value + ", Allowed values are " + Arrays.toString(values()));
    }

}
```

and

```
package com.example.enumhandler.validator;


import com.example.enumhandler.enumerator.GenderTypeEnum;
import jakarta.validation.Constraint;
import jakarta.validation.Payload;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = GenderTypeEnumSubSetValidator.class)
public @interface GenderTypeEnumSubset {
    GenderTypeEnum[] anyOf();
    String message() default "must be any of {anyOf}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and

```
package com.example.enumhandler.validator;

import com.example.enumhandler.enumerator.GenderTypeEnum;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class GenderTypeEnumSubSetValidator implements ConstraintValidator<GenderTypeEnumSubset, GenderTypeEnum> {
    private GenderTypeEnum[] subset;

    @Override
    public void initialize(GenderTypeEnumSubset constraint) {
        this.subset = constraint.anyOf();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(GenderTypeEnum value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value == null || Arrays.asList(subset).contains(value);
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.example.enumhandler.controller;

import com.example.enumhandler.dto.UserDTO;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
public class UserController {


    @GetMapping(path = "/user")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(

            @RequestBody
            @Valid
            UserDTO user

    ){
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .body(user);

    }
}
```

finally

[![enter image description here][6]][6]

and

[![enter image description here][7]][7]

UPEDATE with Error Handler

```
package com.example.enumhandler.exception;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;


@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
class ApiError {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private String status;
    private int code;
    private String message;

}
```

and

```
package com.example.enumhandler.exception;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class UserExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> test(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpServletRequest httpServlet){
        ApiError error = ApiError
                .builder()
                .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.getReasonPhrase())
                .code(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value())
                .message(ex.getLocalizedMessage())
                .build();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

and

[![enter image description here][8]][8]

or

[![enter image description here][9]][9]

but

[![enter image description here][10]][10]

1. Is it possible to not show **"JSON parse error: Cannot construct
   instance of `com.example.enumhandler.enumerator.GenderTypeEnum`,
   problem:"** I don't like show internal code name class;?
2. Is it possible to report, for example,  **"Allowed values are
   [male, female]"** instead of  **"Allowed values are [MALE, FEMALE]"** (aka enum value and not name)?
3. Is it possible to collect all ENUM error in a unique message?

[4]: https://medium.com/@vandernobrel/creating-custom-bean-validation-annotations-2c21f5e24b06  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5t7k.png
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktHH6.png
[7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/llpxz.png
[8]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFKu9.png
[9]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQSgA.png
[10]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Uo0.png

Comment: Check out @ControllerAdvice so you can catch your illegalArgumentException and create a custom output. https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: You can create you own Custom validator for this purpose, and pass the appropriate error message & validation logic.
This article explains the way to valid enums using custom validator annotations
https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validations-enums

Comment: @JamesWagstaff I don't know if your solution is valid for enum

Comment: @JayYadav I tried your solution but sorry doesn't work (update question)

Comment: What is the expected error response you want !! Can you please add that

Comment: @JayYadav the error response is given by "must be any of {anyOf}" message of interface GenderTypeEnumSubset

Answer (score 0):

about **Is it possible to report, for example, "Allowed values are [male, female]" instead of "Allowed values are [MALE, FEMALE]" (aka enum value and not name)?**

```
package com.example.enumhandler.enumerator;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

import java.util.Arrays;

public enum GenderTypeEnum {

    MALE("male"),
    FEMALE("female");


    private final String value;


    private GenderTypeEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private static String[] getNames(Class<? extends Enum<?>> e) {
        return Arrays.stream(e.getEnumConstants())
                .map(Enum::name)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    private static String[] getNamesValue(){
        return Arrays
                .stream(values())
                .map(e -> valueOf(e.name()).value)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getGender(){
        return this.value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static GenderTypeEnum fromValues(String value) {
        for (GenderTypeEnum category : GenderTypeEnum.values()) {
            if (category.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return category;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Unknown enum type "
                        + value
                        + ", Allowed values are "
                        + Arrays.toString(getNamesValue()));
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have missed to add `@Valid` annotation on you controller for your custom annotation to work !!

```
  @GetMapping(path = "/user")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(
            @RequestBody
            @Valid
            UserDTO user) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .body(user);

    }
```

Also one suggestion to use `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependencies instead of `hibernate-validator` as in spring docs !!

Also If you want to handle exception occurred due to invalid enums passed you will need to create custom Exception Handler

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class UserExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
    public void test(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpServletRequest httpServlet){
        //Your code to return your Response here
    }
}
```

`Is it possible to not show "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of com.example.enumhandler.enumerator.GenderTypeEnum, problem:" I don't like show internal code name class;?`

Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64576320/16769477

`Is it possible to report, for example, "Allowed values are [male, female]" instead of "Allowed values are [MALE, FEMALE]" (aka enum value and not name)?`

In your enum classes(HobbyEnum.java) you are passing values in Illegalxception !!

Comment: I updated the question with all your full suggestions but, again, not working

Comment: I am not able to understand, You don't want BadRequest in response is it.. or custom errorRepsonse(POJO) , if so what response do you want in json format.. what fields etc ?

Comment: Updated the code with exception handler, the control will reach here on passing unknown enum value in request payload, you need to return appropriate response

Comment: Yedav. I wish to return an error message saying that the aroment malexxxxx is invalid and valid arguments are male and female without too many frills.

Comment: In all the tutorials and documentations I have not found a valid one evenge though the use of ENUM seems to me quite common

Comment: Try the above approach mentioned in my answer.. write code in the exception handler to display response as of you choice

Comment: Thanks, I kindly ask if you know a good tutorial to do error handling for enum validation?

Comment: Sincerely, I found only pages written to the dickens.

Comment: Update the Question with your suggestions

Comment: Refer this answer to remove unwanted JSON parse message : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64576320/16769477