# How to return a proper validation error for enum types in Spring Boot using pattern and match solution

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wrote an Enum class, an appropriate validator and an @RestControllerAdvice to handle the exception raised:

```
package com.example.enumhandler.enumerator;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

import java.util.Arrays;

    public enum GenderTypeEnum {
    
        MALE("male"),
        FEMALE("female");
    
    
        private final String value;
    
    
        private GenderTypeEnum(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    
        private static String[] getNames(Class<? extends Enum<?>> e) {
            return Arrays.stream(e.getEnumConstants())
                    .map(Enum::name)
                    .toArray(String[]::new);
        }
    
        private static String[] getNamesValue(){
            return Arrays
                    .stream(values())
                    .map(e -> valueOf(e.name()).value)
                    .toArray(String[]::new);
        }
    
        @JsonValue
        public String getGender(){
            return this.value;
        }
    
        @JsonCreator
        public static GenderTypeEnum fromValues(String value) {
            for (GenderTypeEnum category : GenderTypeEnum.values()) {
                if (category.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                    return category;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Unknown enum type "
                            + value
                            + ", Allowed values are: "
                            + Arrays.toString(getNamesValue()));
        }
    }
```

and

```
package com.example.enumhandler.exception;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;


@RestControllerAdvice
public class UserExceptionHandler{

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleHttpMessageNotReadableException(
            HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
            HttpServletRequest request
    ){
        HttpStatus badRequest = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;

        ErrorResponse error = ErrorResponse
                .builder()
                .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                .status(badRequest.getReasonPhrase())
                .code(badRequest.value())
                .message(ex.getLocalizedMessage())
                .build();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, badRequest);
    }
}
```

Everything works but between in the outgoing response the error reports this message:

```
"JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.enumhandler.enumerator.GenderTypeEnum`, problem: Unknown enum type malex, Allowed values are: [male, female]"
```

[image]

I am trying to improve the message in order that only this information is reported:

```
Unknown enum type malex, Allowed values are: [male, female]
```

Searching online, I found this solution that I tried to implement to no avail

[How to return a proper validation error for enum types in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64575842/how-to-return-a-proper-validation-error-for-enum-types-in-spring-boot/64576320#64576320)

There are probably some aspects in the regex that I am missing, plus the author of the solution reports some instructions that expose methods that are probably not present in the Java version (17), such as `match.test()`

```
if (match.test()) {
            return new ErrorObject("value should be: " + match.group(1),  HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
```

Has no one developed a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the root exception that wrapped by `HttpMessageNotReadableException` to get your desired message:

```
final Throwable rootCause = org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(ex);

ErrorResponse error = ErrorResponse
    .builder()
    .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
    .status(badRequest.getReasonPhrase())
    .code(badRequest.value())
    .message(rootCause.getLocalizedMessage()) // Use the original message.
    .build();
```

If you don't want to add apache exception dependency, you can use `getRootCause` of throwable instead:

```
final Throwable rootCause = exception.getRootCause()
```

Comment: Thanks, but final Throwable rootCause = exception.getRootCause() -> rootCause.rootCause.getLocalizedMessage()  can give rise to produce 'NullPointerException' ?

Comment: Yes, in some cases it will throw NPE, therefore I use `org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils.getRootCause` to avoid this.