# How to use a String array from one class in different classes, so that number of lines of code does not become too much

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have created a String array that contains the names of all the cities in India.  So, I don't want to declare it again and again as I need it in many other JAVA classes.
I am working in Android Studio. I use the Strings.xml file for declaring a simple string array. I don't understand what should I do?

```
public String[] cities= { "Bhandup","Mumbai","Visakhapatnam","Coimbatore","Delhi","Bangalore","Pune","Nagpur","Lucknow","Vadodara","Indore","Jalalpur","Bhopal","Kolkata","Kanpur","New Delhi","Faridabad","Rajkot","Ghaziabad","Chennai","Meerut","Agra","Jaipur","Jabalpur","Varanasi","Allahabad","Hyderabad","Noida","Howrah","Thane","Patiala","Chakan","Ahmedabad",

"Manipala","Mangalore","Panvel","Udupi","Rishikesh","Gurgaon","Mathura","Shahjahanpur","Bagpat","Sriperumbudur","Chandigarh","Ludhiana","Palakkad","Kalyan","Valsad","Ulhasnagar","Bhiwani","Shimla","Dehradun","Patna","Unnao","Tiruvallur","Kanchipuram","Jamshedpur","Gwalior","Karur","Erode","Gorakhpur","Ooty","Haldwani","Bikaner","Puducherry","Nalbari","Bellary","Vellore","Naraina","Mandi","Rupnagar","Jodhpur","Roorkee","Aligarh","Indraprast","Karnal","Tanda","Amritsar","Raipur","Pilani","Bilaspur","Srinagar","Guntur","Kakinada","Warangal","Tirumala - Tirupati","Nizamabad","Kadapa","Kuppam","Anantpur","Nalgonda","Potti","Nellore","Rajahmundry","Bagalkot","Kurnool","Secunderabad","Mahatma","Bharuch","Miraj","Nanded","Anand","Gandhinagar","Bhavnagar","Morvi","Aurangabad","Modasa","Patan","Solapur","Kolhapur","Junagadh","Akola","Bhuj","Karad","Jalgaon Jamod","Chandrapur","Maharaj","Dhule","Ponda","Dahod","Navsari","Panjim","Patel","Nashik","Amravati","Somnath","Ganpat","Karwar","Davangere","Raichur","Nagara","Kushalnagar","Hassan","Hubli","Bidar","Belgaum","Mysore","Dharwad","Kolar","TumkÅ«r","Tiruchi","Thiruvananthapuram","Kozhikode","Thrissur","Madurai","Thalassery","Kannur","Karaikudi","Thanjavur","Manor","Idukki","Thiruvarur","Alappuzha","Gandhigram","Kochi","Annamalainagar","Amet","Kottarakara","Kottayam","Tirunelveli","Mohan","Salem","Attingal","Chitra","Chengannur","Guwahati","Kalam","Ranchi","Shillong","Gangtok","Srikakulam","Tezpur","Bhubaneswar","Imphal","Sundargarh","Arunachal","Manipur","Bihar Sharif","Mandal","Dibrugarh","Darbhanga","Gaya","Bhagalpur","Kunwar","Barddhaman","Jadabpur","Kalyani","Cuttack","Barpeta","Jorhat","Kharagpur","Medinipur","Agartala","Saranga","Machilipatnam","Dhanbad","Silchar","Dumka","Kokrajhar","Bankura","Jalpaiguri","Durgapur","Kalinga","Palampur","Jammu","Dwarka","Faridkot","Udaipur","Raigarh","Hisar","Solan","Ajmer","Lala","Gurdaspur","Sultanpur","Jhansi","Vidisha","Jagdalpur","Dipas","Sawi","Etawah","Saharanpur","Ujjain","Kangra","Bhilai","Rohtak","Haryana","Ambala","Bareilly","Bhoj","Kapurthala Town","Sangrur","Pusa","Sagar","Rewa","Bhawan","Rampur","Bhadohi","Cuddalore","Khopoli","Bali","Bhiwandi","Vasai","Badlapur","Sambalpur","Raurkela","Brahmapur","Visnagar","Surendranagar","Ankleshwar","Dahanu","Silvassa","Jamnagar","Dhansura","Muzaffarpur","Wardha","Bodhan","Parappanangadi","Malappuram","Vizianagaram","Mavelikara","Pathanamthitta","Satara","Janjgir","Gold","Himatnagar","Bodinayakkanur","Gandhidham","Mahabalipuram","Nadiad","Virar","Bahadurgarh","Kaithal","Siliguri","Tiruppur","Ernakulam","Jalandhar","Barakpur","Kavaratti","Ratnagiri","Moga","Hansi","Sonipat","Bandra","Aizawl","Itanagar","Nagar","Ghatkopar","Chen","Powai","Bhimavaram","Bhongir","Medak","Karimnagar","Narsapur","Vijayawada","Markapur","Mancherial","Sangli","Moradabad","Alipur","Ichalkaranji","Devgarh","Yavatmal","Hinganghat","Madgaon","Verna","Katra","Bilaspur","Uttarkashi","Muktsar","Bhatinda","Pathankot","Khatauli","Vikasnagar","Kollam","Kovilpatti","Kovvur","Paloncha","Vasco","Alwar","Bijapur","Tinsukia","Ratlam","Kalka","Ladwa","Rajpura","Batala","Hoshiarpur","Katni","Bhilwara","Jhajjar","Lohaghat","Mohali","Dhuri","Thoothukudi","Sivakasi","Coonoor","Shimoga","Kayamkulam","Namakkal","Dharmapuri","Aluva","Antapur","Tanuku","Eluru","Balasore","Hingoli","Quepem","Assagao","Betim","Cuncolim","Ahmednagar","Goa","Caranzalem","Chopda","Petlad","Raipur","Villupuram","Shoranur","Dasua","Gonda","Yadgir","Palladam","Nuzvid","Kasaragod","Paonta Sahib","Sarangi","Anantapur","Kumar","Kaul","Panipat","Uppal","Teri","Tiruvalla","Jamal","Chakra","Narasaraopet","Dharamsala","Ranjan","Garhshankar","Haridwar","Chinchvad","Narela","Aurangabad","Sion","Kalamboli","Chittoor","Wellington","Nagapattinam","Karaikal","Pollachi","Thenkasi","Aranmula","Koni","Ariyalur","Ranippettai","Kundan","Lamba Harisingh","Surana","Ghana","Lanka","Kataria","Kotian","Khan","Salt Lake City","Bala","Vazhakulam","Paravur","Nabha","Ongole","Kaladi","Jajpur","Thenali","Mohala","Mylapore","Bank","Khammam","Ring","Maldah","Kavali","Andheri","Baddi","Mahesana","Nila","Gannavaram","Cumbum","Belapur","Phagwara","Rander","Siuri","Bulandshahr","Bilimora","Guindy","Pitampura","Baharampur","Dadri","Boisar","Shiv","Multi","Bhadath","Ulubari","Palghar","Puras","Sikka","Saha","Godhra","Dam Dam","Ekkattuthangal","Sahibabad","Kalol","Bardoli","Wai","Shirgaon","Nehra","Mangalagiri","Latur","Kottakkal","Rewari","Ponnani","Narayangaon","Hapur","Kalpetta","Khurja","Ramnagar","Neral","Sendhwa","Talegaon Dabhade","Kargil","Manali","Jalalabad","Palani","Sirkazhi","Krishnagiri","Hiriyur","Muzaffarnagar","Kashipur","Gampalagudem","Siruseri","Manjeri","Raniganj","Mahim","Bhusawal","Tirur","Sattur","Angul","Puri","Khurda","Dharavi","Ambur","Vashi","Arch","Colaba","Hosur","Kota","Hugli","Anantnag","Murshidabad","Jharsuguda","Jind","Neyveli","Vaniyambadi","Srikalahasti","Liluah","Pali","Bokaro","Sidhi","Asansol","Darjeeling","Kohima","Shahdara","Chandannagar","Nadgaon","Haripad","Sitapur","Vapi","Bambolim","Baidyabati","Connaught Place","Singtam","Shyamnagar","Sikar","Choolai","Mayapur","Puruliya","Habra","Kanchrapara","Goregaon","Tiptur","Kalpakkam","Serampore","Konnagar","Port Blair","Canning","Mahad","Alibag","Pimpri","Panchgani","Karjat","Vaikam","Mhow","Lakhimpur","Madhoganj","Kheri","Gudivada","Avanigadda","Nayagarh","Bemetara","Bhatapara","Ramgarh","Dhubri","Goshaingaon","Bellare","Puttur","Narnaul","Porbandar","Keshod","Dhrol","Kailaras","Morena","Deolali","Banda","Orai","Fatehpur","Mirzapur","Adilabad","Pithapuram","Ramavaram","Amalapuram","Champa","Ambikapur","Korba"}

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cities);
city3.setThreshold(1);
city3.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I need the last lines of code in other classes too, but the array name "cities" will remain unknown there. How can I prevent not to write such long code of array again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static String[] cities={};
```

and access with classname

Answer (score 1):

Declare it as public static so you can access it in any class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `enum` with the cities and a method to get the enum values as `String` array:

```
public enum Cities {
    Bhandup,Mumbai,Visakhapatnam, ...;

    // Returns the cities as a string array
    public static String[] names() {
        return Arrays.toString(Cities.values()).replaceAll("^.|.$", "").split(", ");
    }
}
```

The `names` method is from: [Getting all names in an enum as a String[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783295/getting-all-names-in-an-enum-as-a-string)

And call it like that:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Cities.names());
city3.setThreshold(1);
city3.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

write down in string.xml

```
<string-array name="cities">
    <item>Surat</item>
    <item>Ahemdabad</item>
</string-array>
```

then reuse it any class like this way

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getResources().getTextArray(R.array.cities));
```

Answer (score 0):

cities array are like constant you can better use static final for better code and memory.

```
public static final String[] cities={};
```