# Java concatenate List of enum to String

Tags: java, enums, concatenation

Having a list of enum value, I need to convert it to a single string separated by some character.

```
enum Level {
  LOW,
  MEDIUM,
  HIGH
}

Set<Level> levels = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Level.LOW, Level.HIGH));
```

The expected result :

```
String result = "LOW, HIGH"
```

Is there a `String.join` for enum?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: convert List<String> to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting all names in an enum as a String\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783295/getting-all-names-in-an-enum-as-a-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a Strings.join for enum, as such, but you can map the set of levels into Strings and then join them, for example:

```
levels.stream().map(Enum::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

Would yield (with your original set)

```
jshell> enum Level {
   ...>   LOW,
   ...>   MEDIUM,
   ...>   HIGH
   ...> }
|  created enum Level

jshell> Set<Level> levels = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Level.LOW, Level.HIGH));
levels ==> [LOW, HIGH]

jshell> levels.stream().map(Enum::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
$3 ==> "LOW,HIGH"
```

Comment: Answers should not be just code, please provide a summary of what this is actually doing so other users can understand what is happening.

Comment: Much better, it just helps others understand what your code does that's all; can be especially helpful to those just starting out +1

Answer (score 10):

Here is one possible version (Java 8+)

```
enum Levels {
  LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH;
}
...
 String s = EnumSet.allOf(Levels.class).stream().map(Enum::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));

// EnumSet.of(Levels.LOW, Levels.HIGH) if you want some specific enums
System.out.println(s);
```

The result is:

```
LOW,MEDIUM,HIGH
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to somehow invoke the `toString()` method of your `enum Levels`, maybe by means of `HashSet.stream()` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Level> levels = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Level.LOW, Level.HIGH));
    List<String> levelStrings = levels.stream()
                                    .map(Level::toString)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    String result = String.join(", ", levelStrings);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
LOW, HIGH
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
Set<LevelsEnum> levels = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(LevelsEnum.LOW, LevelsEnum.HIGH));

String result = levels.stream()
        .map(LevelsEnum::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(result);
```