# what is the advantage using iterator?

Tags: java, loops

```
for(Element e : elementList)

for (Iterator<Element> itr = elementList.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
```

First one is much simpler. Are there any advantages or reasons that I want to do the second one?

Comment: They do the same thing, you can use the second one when you want to use `remove()` method.

Comment: Did you measure the time each takes? Is this a trick question where one method has a lot of cache hits and the other has a lot of misses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally both of them use iterator, the only difference is that code is more clear and shorter when you used enhanced for loop. Here is what javadoc says about both:

Iterating over a collection is uglier than it needs to be. Consider the following method, which takes a collection of timer tasks and cancels them:

```
void cancelAll(Collection<TimerTask> c) {
    for (Iterator<TimerTask> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
        i.next().cancel();
}
```

The iterator is just clutter. Furthermore, it is an opportunity for error. The iterator variable occurs three times in each loop: that is two chances to get it wrong. The for-each construct gets rid of the clutter and the opportunity for error. Here is how the example looks with the for-each construct:

```
void cancelAll(Collection<TimerTask> c) {
    for (TimerTask t : c)
        t.cancel();
}
```

When you see the colon (:) read it as “in.” The loop above reads as “for each TimerTask t in c.” As you can see, the for-each construct combines beautifully with generics. It preserves all of the type safety, while removing the remaining clutter. Because you don't have to declare the iterator, you don't have to provide a generic declaration for it. (The compiler does this for you behind your back, but you need not concern yourself with it.)

For complete description about why we should use for-each loop and not iterator, read this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 2):

The first form was introduced in Java 5, and the second form is mostly found in legacy code from earlier versions of the language. Nonetheless, there are a few situations where you still need to use the second form; for example, if the loop needs to be able to remove some  (or all) of the elements as they're iterated over, then you need to have `itr` so you can call its `remove` method.

Answer (score 1):

[Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) can [remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) the element from the collection , which cannot be done using for each loop

Answer (score 0):

There is No performance difference. But by using iterator you will have more functionalities to be used. For example you can  reference the Iterator in your loop. This allows you to do things like remove collection items getting a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

You can use following

```
for (Iterator<Element> itr = elementList.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){
     if(o meets some condition){
          itr.remove();
     }
}
```

but not this

```
   for(Element e : elementList){
         if(o meets some condition){
              elementList.remove(e);
         }
    }
```

But if this difference doesn't bother you then you can use the one that comforts your.

[similar so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator)

Answer (score 0):

They are very much the same. Consider this code

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IteratorTest {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new Object());
    list.add(new Object());

    for(Object o : list) 
      System.out.println(o);

    for(Iterator<Object> itr = list.iterator();itr.hasNext();) 
      System.out.println(itr.next());


  }
}
```

We then compile it and disassemble it using

```
javap -c IteratorTest
```

and get the following bytecode for the main method

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class java/util/ArrayList
       3: dup           
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1      
       8: aload_1       
       9: new           #4                  // class java/lang/Object
      12: dup           
      13: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
      16: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/util/ArrayList.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      19: pop           
      20: aload_1
      21: new           #4                  // class java/lang/Object
      24: dup           
      25: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
      28: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/util/ArrayList.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      31: pop           
      32: aload_1       
      33: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/util/ArrayList.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
      36: astore_2      
      37: aload_2       
      38: invokeinterface #7,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
      43: ifeq          63
      46: aload_2       
      47: invokeinterface #8,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
      52: astore_3      
      53: getstatic     #9                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      56: aload_3       
      57: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      60: goto          37
      63: aload_1       
      64: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/util/ArrayList.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
      67: astore_2      
      68: aload_2       
      69: invokeinterface #7,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
      74: ifeq          92
      77: getstatic     #9                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      80: aload_2       
      81: invokeinterface #8,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
      86: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      89: goto          68
      92: return        
}
```

Lines 32 to 60 are the first loop and lines 63 to 89 are the second loop. You will notice that they're pretty much the same - just with the names of some locals changed and slight  reordering.

Therefore, as the compiler produces the same bytecode for the two expressions they are the same.