# How to add objects to an array by using their class name, then calling any of their methods?

Tags: java, casting, arraylist, type-conversion, converters

I am trying to add cards to a list by using their class name, then I want to call one of their methods.  How can I do that? I have this for now:

Into the super class Card:

```
public static ArrayList<Object> CreateAllCards() throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        ArrayList<Object> cardArray = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int n = 0; n<cardList.length; n++)
        {
            if (isCardAllowedToBeCreated[n])
            {
                Class card = Class.forName(cardList[n]);
                cardArray.add(card);
            }
        }

        return cardArray;
    }

    static String[] cardList = {
        "CrtAbyssalSpecter",
        "CrtAirElemental",
        "ArtAladdinsRing",
        "SorAmbitionsCost",
        "CrtAnabaShaman",
        "CrtAngelOfMercy",
        "CrtAngelicPage",
        //...
    };
}
```

Somewhere else, my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    ArrayList<Object> cardList = Card.CreateAllCards();

    for (int n=0; n<cardList.size(); n++)
    {
        if (cardList.get(n) instanceof Creature)
        {
            // How to call a specific method?
        }
    }

}
```

Also, is there a way to directly create an arraylist of Card by using each card name rather than creating an arraylist of object (by each card name) like I do?

Comment: Do the classes `ArtAladdinsRing` define a default constructor?

Comment: Yes it does (minimum 15 characters blablabla).

Comment: Is there a reason why you are storing the class names as strings? Why not having a `static class []` to avoid the `CreateCards` method? Also how the `isCardAllowedToBeCreated[n]` decides which class to create or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filling the list with objects that represent classes; you are not creating objects of them. To create objects [call the `newInstance` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html):

```
            Class card = Class.forName(cardList[n]);
            // Create object by calling the default no-arg constructor:
            cardArray.add(card.newInstance());
```

After that you can call specific methods by casting, like already suggested by the other answer:

```
    if (cardList.get(n) instanceof Creature)
    {
        Creature c = (Creature) cardList.get(n);
        c.creatureSpecificMethod();
    }
```

There might be a better, more flexible, object oriented approach though. Don't these "card" objects have anything in common? If they do, they should probably implement the same interface or inherit from the same super class, and checks like "if the current card is a creature card do X" could be kept to a minimum. See **["Prefer Polymorphism Over InstanceOf and Downcasting."](http://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/PreferPoly.html)**

**Update:**

To create a list of `Cards` you need these modifications: First declare the list as a list of `Card`:

```
ArrayList<Card> cardArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then use the `asSubclass` method to "cast" the result of `forName` into a subclass of `Card`:

```
Class<? extends Card> card = Class.forName(cardList[n]).asSubclass(Card.class);
cardArray.add(card.newInstance());
```

Comment: The main thing is that I must instantiate each object by their object name. Is there a way to create an arraylist of <Card> instead of <Object> and still instantiate each card by their class name?

Comment: Do you have a class called `Card`? Are CrtAbyssalSpecter, CrtAirElemental, etc subclasses of `Card`?

Comment: Yes I do (Minimum 15 char blablabla).

Answer (score 2):

Using casting, like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
{

    ArrayList<Object> cardList = Card.CreateAllCards();

    for(Object card : cardList)
    {
        if(card instanceof Creature)
        {
            Creature creature = (Creature) card;
            creature.creatureMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally I changed your `for` loop style to the more efficient `for each`.

Comment: Isn't foreach loop slower than the normal for loop?

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati Not in this case, as before he was using `.get(int element)` every time which has O(n) efficiency, whereas foreach uses the iterator which is O(1), see this answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2113226/1276341

Comment: Thanks for sharing that answer. I was taught like that in my GameDev class where we need to query a list of almost 200 objects in a while loop which loops at 30 times in a second.

Comment: `ArrayList.get(int)` is Θ(1) - an array lookup takes constant time.

Comment: The `CreateAllCards` method returns an array of **classes** not instances