# For-each vs Iterator. Which will be the better option

Tags: java, foreach, iterator

Consider the following scenario.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I added the `String` values for this list.

I used following ways to go each and every element in the list.

Option one- use `for-each`

```
for (String i : list) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Option two- use `Iterator`

```
Iterator it=list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

I just want to know is there any performance advantage if I use `for-each` instead of `Iterator`. And also is it a bad practice to use Iterator now a days in Java?

Comment: I think for each uses the iterator

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`for-each` is syntactic sugar for using `iterators` (approach 2).

You might need to use `iterators` if you need to modify collection in your loop. First approach will throw exception.

```
for (String i : list) {
    System.out.println(i);
    list.remove(i); // throws exception
} 

Iterator it=list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(it.next());
    it.remove(); // valid here
}
```

Comment: Of course its good to remember that adding/removing items from the collection that you're looping over is not good practice, for the very reason that you highlighted.

Answer (score 19):

The difference is largely syntactic sugar except that an Iterator can remove items from the Collection it is iterating. Technically, enhanced for loops allow you to loop over anything that's Iterable, which at a minimum includes both Collections and arrays.

Don't worry about performance differences. Such micro-optimization is an irrelevant distraction. If you need to remove items as you go, use an Iterator. Otherwise for loops tend to be used more just because they're more readable ie:

```
for (String s : stringList) { ... }
```

vs:

```
for (Iterator<String> iter = stringList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
  String s = iter.next();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 13):

`for-each` is an advanced looping construct. Internally it creates an Iterator and iterates over the Collection. Only possible advantage of using an actual Iterator object over the `for-each` construct is that you can modify your collection using Iterator's methods like `.remove()`. Modifying the collection without using Iterator's methods while iterating will produce a [ConcurrentModificationException.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

Comment: *Can* not "will" led to ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: One confusion here if enhanced for each uses Iterator internally why there is restriction in element removal while iteration?

Comment: @shaun because you don't have access to it :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple answers: No and no.

Internally the `for-each` loop creates an `Iterator` to iterate through the collection.

The advantage of using the `Iterator` explicitly is that you can access the `Iterator`s method.

Comment: but why the Iterator class does not need to be imported in the code?

Comment: @Dakatine because the import is done implicitly by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do this is in java 8 is,

```
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here are some useful links.

1. [Java 8 Iterable.forEach() vs foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635398/java-8-iterable-foreach-vs-foreach-loop)
2. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2461744/java-language/java-language-iterating-over-collections-in-java-8.html
3. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html

Comment: why do you think it's better using list.foreach()? in as such feaeach() method you cannot modify a extern var and have to copy it as final or wrap it in an array.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is simple code snippet to check the performance of `For-each` vs `Iterator` vs `for` for the traversal of `ArrayList<String>`, performed on Java version 8.**

```
        long MAX = 2000000;

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (long i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {

            list.add("" + i);
        }

        /**
         * Checking with for each iteration.
         */
        long A = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (String data : list) {
            // System.out.println(data);
        }

        long B = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(B - A + "ms");

        /**
         * Checking with Iterator method
         */

        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
            // System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }

        long C = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(C - B + "ms");

        /**
         * Checking with normal iteration.
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            list.get((int) (i % (MAX - i)));
            // System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }

        long D = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(D - C + "ms");
```

**Average Output values:**

```
19ms
9ms
27ms
```

> **Result Analysis:**
> `Iterator` (9ms) < `For-each` (19ms) < `For` (27ms)
>
> Here **`Iterator` has the best performance** and `For` has the least performance. However `For-each` performance lies somewhere in between.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` uses iterators under the hood anyway. It really is just syntactic sugar.

Consider the following program:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Whatever {
    private final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    public void main() {
        for(Integer i : list) {
        }
    }
}
```

Let's compile it with `javac Whatever.java`,
And read the disassembled bytecode of `main()`, using `javap -c Whatever`:

```
public void main();
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: getfield      #4                  // Field list:Ljava/util/List;
     4: invokeinterface #5,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
     9: astore_1
    10: aload_1
    11: invokeinterface #6,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
    16: ifeq          32
    19: aload_1
    20: invokeinterface #7,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
    25: checkcast     #8                  // class java/lang/Integer
    28: astore_2
    29: goto          10
    32: return
```

We can see that `foreach` compiles down to a program which:

- Creates iterator using `List.iterator()`
- If `Iterator.hasNext()`: invokes `Iterator.next()` and continues loop

---

As for "why doesn't this useless loop get optimized out of the compiled code? we can see that it doesn't do anything with the list item": well, it's possible for you to code your iterable such that `.iterator()` has side-effects, or so that `.hasNext()` has side-effects or meaningful consequences.

You could easily imagine that an iterable representing a scrollable query from a database might do something dramatic on `.hasNext()` (like contacting the database, or closing a cursor because you've reached the end of the result set).

So, even though we can prove that nothing happens in the loop body… it is more expensive (intractable?) to prove that nothing meaningful/consequential happens when we iterate. The compiler has to leave this empty loop body in the program.

The best we could hope for would be a compiler *warning*. It's interesting that `javac -Xlint:all Whatever.java` does *not* warn us about this empty loop body. IntelliJ IDEA does though. Admittedly I have configured IntelliJ to use Eclipse Compiler, but that may not be the reason why.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace items in your List, I would go old school with a for loop

```
for (int nIndex=0; nIndex < list.size(); nIndex++) {
  Obj obj = (Obj) list.get(nIndex);

  // update list item
  list.set(nIndex, obj2);
}
```