# Should I use iterators or simple loops?

Tags: java, loops, iterator, doubly-linked-list

I'm doing a Java implementation for a Doubly-linked list.

I have some methods like this:

```
private DLNode<T> getNodeAtPosition(int position) throws DLListException {
  verifySize(this.listSize(), position);
  DLNode<T> result = this.first;
  for (int counter = 0; counter < position; counter++) { // <=======
    result = result.next;
  }
  return result;
}
```

It can be done either with for/while loops or with iterators. Which one optimizes those methods? That's a important thing if you're trying to do a very used ADT.

I'm not meaning for-each loops, I mean loops where you have to stop before the end as this one, or generally any loop that has more than one termination condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterator vs for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267919/iterator-vs-for)

Comment: When traversing linked list by next, you can use any.

Comment: you can even use a while loop ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I use iterators instead of for/while loops? *(In this situation where the loop has more than one termination condition.)*

*(My postscript above)*

That's primarily a matter of opinion, but if the simple `for` loop does what you want, avoiding the overhead of creating an `Iterator` object and calling its methods seems a reasonably objective reason for sticking with the simple `for` loop. Less for the JVM's JIT to optimize, particularly if you're writing a utility class that will be used in lots of places (e.g., a doubly-linked list).

Comment: So you mean that if I want to optimize it, it will be better with an iterator, but in any other case it's better to avoid it, right?

Comment: @CarlosMorenteLozano: No, I mean that if a `for` loop does what you need, then you can avoid the JVM having to optimize creating the iterator and calling its methods -- by just using a `for` loop instead.