# Iterate over consecutive object pairs in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to get pairs of objects from an `ArrayList` so I can perform calculations between the elements of each object. Ideally it should iterate over pairs of objects. For example in a `List` with `{obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4}` it should go over `{obj1, obj2}`, `{obj2, obj3}` and `{obj3, obj4}`.

What I have tried so far is as follows.

```java
public class Sum {
    public ArrayList<Double> calculateSum(ArrayList<Iter> iter) {
        ListIterator<Iter> it = iter.listIterator();
        ArrayList<Double> sums = new ArrayList<>();
        
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Iter it1 = it.next();
            Iter it2;
            if(it.hasNext()){
                it2 = it.next();
            } else {    break;  }
            
            double sum = it1.getValue() + it2.getValue();
            sums.add(sum);
        }
        return sums;
    }
}
```

Here, it just iterates as `{obj1, obj2}` and `{obj3, obj4}`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably you'd need to iterate with an indexing variable.

Comment: @ChetanKinger: Sorry my bad. It should be it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very normal loop, except that you need to loop up to `list.size() - 1`, the ***before last*** element of the array.

```
public ArrayList<Double> calculateSum(ArrayList<Iter> list) {
    ArrayList<Double> sums = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        double sum = list.get(i).getValue() + list.get(i + 1).getValue();
        sums.add(sum);
    }
    return sums;
}
```

**EDIT**

Using an iterator in this case will ***not*** be faster than doing a normal loop and just makes the logic unnecessarily complicated and can easily introduce bugs.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using an iterator instead of for loops? This will be for a large dataset and I'd prefer to get the faster performance boost from using an Iterator.

Comment: See my edit.  If your method receives an `ArrayList` as your code shows, using an `Iterator` will ***not*** make it more performant.  Keep it simple.

Comment: @sstan - Why do you define `sum` over and over at each iteration? Won't it be more efficient to place the decleration `double sum` **before** the loop?

Comment: @TDG: I think you'll enjoy [this reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803674/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop).  But basically, whether the variable is defined outside or inside, the generated byte code is the same, and therefore the performance is the same.  But by declaring it inside the loop, I gain readability.

Comment: @sstan: Out of curiosity from another answer here, is there a performance difference from setting the list size before the loop instead of being called everytime the loop is iterated?

Comment: @dshgna: Yes, there could be a little difference.  I would be very suprised if you were able to notice the difference, but feel free to assign the `list.size()` result to a variable before looping.  It certainly won't hurt, and your code will still look good :)

Answer (score 3):

A little modification to Davide's answer

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i ++) {
    sums.add(list.get(i) + list.get(i+1));
}
```

Because the OP wanted {obj1, obj2} {obj2, obj3} ...etc

**Using a iterator**

```
itr = list.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
   Double x = itr.next();
   if(itr.hasNext()){
      x+= itr.next();
      sum.add(x);}
   itr.previous();
  }
```

This is not recommended.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using an iterator instead of for loops? This will be for a large dataset and I'd prefer to get the faster performance boost from using an Iterator.

Comment: Also using itr.previous would actually make the performance slower, I guess?

Comment: Yeah and hence it is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature can be used to achieve the desired result:

```java
iter.stream()
        .gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(2))
        .map(list -> list.get(0).getValue() + list.get(1).getValue())
        .toList();
```

This uses the new [`Stream.gather`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)) method with the new built-in [`Gatherers.windowSliding`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowSliding(int)) gatherer to convert the lists's stream from `Stream<Iter>` to a pairwise `Stream<List<Iter>>`.  Each of these two-element lists is then transformed to the sum of their values using the existing [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) method.

## Example

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

->

[
  [0, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 3],
  [3, 4]
]

->

[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

## Javadocs

[`Gatherer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.

[`Stream.gather`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherers.windowSliding`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowSliding(int))

> Returns a Gatherer that gathers elements into windows -- encounter-ordered groups of elements -- of a given size, where each subsequent window includes all elements of the previous window except for the least recent, and adds the next element in the stream. […]
>
> Example:
>
> ```java
> // will contain: [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8]]
> List<List<Integer>> windows2 =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(2)).toList();
>
> // will contain: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
> List<List<Integer>> windows6 =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(6)).toList();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a for loop and stop at element before last one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < iter.size() - 1; i++) {
    Iter first = iter.get(i);
    Iter second = iter.get(i + 1);
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: why `i+=2`? it becomes `obj1,obj2` and `obj3,obj4`

Comment: This will also work in the same way as it does for the OP already... Why are you adding 2 to `i` on every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
public ArrayList<Double> calculateSum(ArrayList<Iter> inputList) {
    ArrayList<Double> sums = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int inputSize =  inputList.size(); // size should be saved as an int , instead of calling size() over the list again and again in for loop 
    int incVar = 1; // 1 incremented value
    double sum = 0.0d;
    for(int i = 0; incVar < inputSize; i++,incVar++){
          sum = inputList.get(i).getValue() + inputList.get(incVar).getValue();
          sums.add(sum);
    }
    return sums;
}
```

Comment: The input here is an ArrayList of objects not doubles.

Comment: But that `Object` can be casted down to `Double` in order to get value from the object. Right ?

Comment: The requirement here is to get the value of a particular property of an object. I'd have simply used an array if I wanted to do calculations on doubles!

Comment: Would that Going to make any difference. Just you need to change the `Object` to `Iter` and call `getValue()` its customized according to you.I just tried to give you the logic

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static ArrayList<Double> calculateSum(ArrayList<Iter> iter) {
     ListIterator<Iter> it = iter.listIterator();
     ArrayList<Double> sums = new ArrayList<>();
     if (it.hasNext()) {
         double prev = it.next().getValue();
         while (it.hasNext()) {
             double current = it.next().getValue();
             double sum = prev + current;
             sums.add(sum);
             prev = current;
         }
     }
     return sums;
 }
```