# Java: What's the preferable way to iterate over a set?

Tags: java

I've been teached in college that one has to create an iterator to loop over a set.

```
java.util.HashSet<String> set = new java.util.HashSet<String>();

set.add("Green");
set.add("Blue");
set.add("Yellow");
set.add("Orange");
set.add("Red");

Iterator it = set.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    String current = (String) it.next();

    System.out.println(current);
}
```

Now I've seen in the code of colleagues that there is a more simple way to accomplish it. Using a for-loop:

```
for (String str : set) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

I asked myself why the approach with the for-loop wasn't showed in college.

**Has the approach with the for-loop disadvantages?**

**What's the preferable way to iterate over a set and why?**

Comment: Use the enhanced for loop if you don't need to remove from the set during iteration.

Comment: And if you use the iterator approach, use `Iterator<String>`, not raw `Iterator`.

Comment: Did you see the link - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/90/collections/5856/iterating-over-collections  ???

Comment: Ahh, ... thanks. That makes sense. One needs the iterator to change the data structure while iterating over it.

Comment: No search effort: https://www.google.pl/search?q=java+why+use+iterator+instead+of+for+loop , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267919/iterator-vs-for , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879255/performance-of-traditional-for-loop-vs-iterator-foreach-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, as behind the scenes you'll still be using an iterator.

That is, the [p-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-code_machine) will be more a less the same.