# Effective method to print Linked List as far as memory is concerned

Tags: java, linked-list

We can print Linked list with Iterator and for loop. How does it differ as far as memory allocation is concerned? Which one is more effective?

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> placesToVisit = new LinkedList<String>();
        placesToVisit.add("Sydney");
        placesToVisit.add("Melbourne");
        placesToVisit.add("Brisbane");
        placesToVisit.add("Perth");

        printListWithoutFor(placesToVisit);
        printListWithFor(placesToVisit);

    }

    private static void printListWithoutFor(LinkedList<String> linkedList) {
        Iterator<String> i = linkedList.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Now visiting " + i.next());
        }
        System.out.println("=========================");
    }

    private static void printListWithFor(LinkedList<String> linkedList){
        for (int i=0; i<linkedList.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Now visiting " + linkedList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An iterator is better than a loop. You may find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267919/iterator-vs-for)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: An iterator is better than a loop. You may find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267919/iterator-vs-for)

Comment: Not directly your question but for iterating concerns, ArrayList should be favored over LinkedList.

Answer (score 1):

Printing with `Iterator` is more time efficient (since it iterates over the linked list just once, where each `linkedList.get(i)` requires partial iteration over the list), even though it requires a little more memory (for the allocation of the `Iterator`). I wouldn't choose a for loop over `Iterator` just to save that one instance allocation.

In terms of space complexity, both ways requires `O(1)` space.

Therefore you should prefer the method with the better time complexity - the print with `Iterator` takes `O(n)` time while the for loop takes `O(n^2)` time.

Answer (score 0):

Just not only for memory concern but also to avoid indexing issues you can find iterator better than loops. please find more information [here](http://An%20iterator%20is%20better%20than%20a%20loop.%20You%20may%20find%20more%20information%20[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267919/iterator-vs-for))