# Java integer list

Tags: java

I am trying to make java go trough a list of numbers.
It chooses the first one, gives this as output, waits/sleeps like 2000 milliseconds and then give the next one as output, waits 2000 milliseconds, etc.

They should not be listed behind eachother so when my list is:
10
20
30
40
50

It should not give as output: 10 20 30 40 50.
But just 50.

It would be even better if it was able to repeat itself.

So far i tried:

```
List<Integer> myCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myCoords.add(10);
myCoords.add(20);
myCoords.add(30);
myCoords.add(40);
myCoords.add(50);
Iterator<Integer> myListIterator = someList.iterator(); 
while (myListIterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer coord = myListIterator.next();     
}
```

But this has no timer, and i am not sure if this will only show '20' or '10 20 30 40 50' as output.
And i dont really know how to put a sleep/wait command and a repeat command in this :s (might have overlooked the repeat command if its already in)

**Edit**
Tyvm all, i can go on with the rest of the coding now :)

Comment: This program doesn’t have any output.

Comment: In addition, you contradict yourself. First you say `It chooses the first one, gives this as output, ... and then give the next one as output` then later `It should not give as output: 10 20 30 40 50. But just 50.`

Comment: @Brian Roach he means it rewinds and rewrites the line. (`\r`)

Comment: @mathepic - Impressive, I could not have pulled that from the question without you pointing it out.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to rewrite a line on console, print a control character `\r` (carriage return).

```
List<Integer> myCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myCoords.add(10);
myCoords.add(20);
myCoords.add(30);
myCoords.add(40);
myCoords.add(50);
Iterator<Integer> myListIterator = myCoords.iterator(); 
while (myListIterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer coord = myListIterator.next();     
    System.out.print("\r");
    System.out.print(coord);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: this might be late but,i just for started with list. Whats the difference between using a for loop like; for(i<list.size();i++) and a while loop with hasNext()?

Comment: @alexsummers It is just a different method of accessing collection elements. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99164/iterate-with-for-loop-or-while-loop and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89891/what-are-the-benefits-of-the-iterator-interface-in-java

Answer (score 2):

code that works, but output is:

```
10
20
30
40
50
```

so:

```
    List<Integer> myCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myCoords.add(10);
    myCoords.add(20);
    myCoords.add(30);
    myCoords.add(40);
    myCoords.add(50);
    for (Integer number : myCoords) {
        System.out.println(number);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert a sleep command you can use Thread.sleep(2000). So the code would be:

```
List<Integer> myCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myCoords.add(10);
myCoords.add(20);
myCoords.add(30);
myCoords.add(40);
myCoords.add(50);
Iterator<Integer> myListIterator = someList.iterator(); 
while (myListIterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer coord = myListIterator.next();    
    System.out.println(coord);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

This would output:
 10
 20
 30
 40
 50

If you want the numbers after each other you could use: System.out.print(coord +" " ); and if you want to repeat the section you can put it in another while loop.

```
List<Integer> myCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myCoords.add(10);
myCoords.add(20);
myCoords.add(30);
myCoords.add(40);
myCoords.add(50);
while(true)
    Iterator<Integer> myListIterator = someList.iterator(); 
    while (myListIterator.hasNext()) {
        Integer coord = myListIterator.next();    
        System.out.print(coord + " ");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

This would output: 10 20 30 40 50 10 20 30 40 50 ... and never stop until you kill the program.

Edit: You do have to put the sleep command in a try catch block

Comment: So what i change in that piece of code to make it just rewrite the previous number? something with the System.out.print(coord + " "); ? And 'try catch block' ? That string looks ok for me in the way u just wrote it :P

Comment: AH, so like: try{     Thread.sleep(2000);   }catch(Exception e){    // handle the exception...   };  instead of Thread.Sleep(2000);

Comment: About the rewrite, or did u mean it is rewriting its previous output?

Comment: 'try and catch block' is relevant here because the method sleep may throw an exception. You can learn about it more here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Ah so it would become: (see my 2nd post in this question)

Answer (score 1):

Let's use some java 8 feature:

```
IntStream.iterate(10, x -> x + 10).limit(5)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you need to store the numbers you can collect them into a collection eg:

```
List numbers = IntStream.iterate(10, x -> x + 10).limit(5)
  .boxed()
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And some delay added:

```
IntStream.iterate(10, x -> x + 10).limit(5)
  .forEach(x -> {
    System.out.println(x);
    try {
      Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // Do something with the exception
    }  
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

So it would become:

```
List<Integer> myCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myCoords.add(10);
myCoords.add(20);
myCoords.add(30);
myCoords.add(40);
myCoords.add(50);
while(true)
    Iterator<Integer> myListIterator = myCoords.iterator(); 
    while (myListIterator.hasNext()) {
        Integer coord = myListIterator.next();    
        System.out.print("\r" + coord);
        try{
    Thread.sleep(2000);
  }catch(Exception e){
   // handle the exception...
  }
    }
}
```

Comment: To remove previous outcome: `System.out.print("\r" + coord);`

Comment: :O, hmm.. how else can i make it rewrite the previous outcome u think?

Comment: with System.out.print(coord + " "); instead of the System.out.print("\r" + coord); perhaps?

Comment: and not `someList.` but your list - means -> ` Iterator<Integer> myListIterator = myCoords.iterator(); `

Comment: What operating system are you using and where are you printing to? "\r" works on Linux/Mac terminal (tested) and should work in Windows console. But if you are looking at the output in some IDE (NetBeans, Eclipse) then it might not work.